# How to create animated snowfall?

Tags: dynamic, random, animation, generative-art

Well, the title is self-explanatory. What sorts of snowfall can we generate using *Mathematica*? There are two options I suggest to consider:

1) Continuous GIF animations with smallest possible number of frames.

2) `Dynamic`-based animations.

Comment: Seams a bit broad, but [given the season...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBWgmQYAQ90) ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I try :)

Comment: Do I smell [confetti](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1900/131)?

Comment: OMG! Mathematica will never cease to amaze me!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

My simple version using `Image`:

```
size = 300;
r = ListConvolve[DiskMatrix[#], 
     RandomInteger[BernoulliDistribution[0.001], {5 size, size}], {1, 1}] & /@ {1.5, 2, 3};
Dynamic[Image[(r[[#]] = RotateRight[r[[#]], #]) & /@ {1, 2, 3}; Total[r[[All, ;; size]]]]]
```

**Update**

A slightly prettier version, same basic idea but now with flakes.

```
flake := Module[{arm},
   arm = Accumulate[{{0, 0.1}}~Join~RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 2}]];
   arm = arm.Transpose@RotationMatrix[{arm[[-1]], {0, 1}}];
   arm = arm~Join~Rest@Reverse[arm.{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
   Polygon[Flatten[arm.RotationMatrix[# \[Pi]/3] & /@ Range[6], 1]]];

snowfield[flakesize_, size_, num_] := 
  Module[{x = 100/flakesize}, 
   ImageData@
    Image[Graphics[{White, 
       Table[Translate[
         Rotate[flake, RandomReal[{0, \[Pi]/6}]], {RandomReal[{0, x}],
           RandomReal[{0, 5 x}]}], {num}]}, Background -> Black, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, x}, {0, 5 x}}], ImageSize -> {size, 5 size}]];

size = 300;

r = snowfield @@@ {{1, size, 500}, {1.5, size, 250}, {2, size, 50}};
Dynamic[Image[(r[[#]] = RotateRight[r[[#]], #]) & /@ {1, 2, 3}; 
  Total[r[[All, ;; size]]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Simple and niiice +1

Comment: this is excellent! +1!

Comment: Symbolic new upvote for the edit +1

Comment: This is really so very pretty!

Comment: This is incredible!!

Comment: Excellent! Could you add snow accumulation effect?

Comment: This really deserves an animated gif.  Here's one if you want to edit the answer to include it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbb1bq1cbcr73vp/snowflakes.gif. It needs to be downloaded to see it animated.

Comment: The snowflake-generation method in `flake` is really nice.

Comment: Hi Simon. Happy Holidays! FYI I used your snowflake in [my Christmas card project](https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/silviah/Published/xmas.html). (It's deployed on the Wolfram cloud as an API.) Though I can't upvote again, still, thank you so much!

Answer (score 32):

I happened to create some snowflakes and snow fall a couple weeks back, and its nice to have some place to share with others!

First, we create some algorithmically generated snowflakes with some randomness using a kind of iterated function system based off the 6-pointed "star" shown below.

```
H = Table[{Cos[n*Pi/3], Sin[n*Pi/3]}, {n, 0, 5, 1}];

Graphics@Table[Line[{{0, 0}, H[[i]]}],{i, 1, 6, 1}]
```

[image: 6-pointed star]

To construct the snowflake we just make copies of this star which are translated by some random amount and rotated (for 6-fold symmetry), and scaled in size.

We can seed some random real numbers to generate unique snowflakes

```
rr[n_] := (SeedRandom[n]; RandomReal[])

SnowFlake[Q_, x_, y_, spin_, size_, k_, h_, opacity_, scale_, N_, PR_, IS_] :=
Graphics[{
 Rotate[
 Translate[
 Scale[
  Table[
   Table[
    Rotate[
    Translate[
    Scale[
       Table[
        {AbsoluteThickness[k*h^(n - 1)], Opacity[opacity], White,
         Line[
          {{0, 0}, H[[i]]}]},
        {i, 1, 6, 1}],   
    scale^(n - 1)],
    {If[n == 1, 0, rr[Q*n]], 0}],
    If[n == 1, 0, (j + rr[Q*n])*Pi/3], {0, 0}],
   {j, 0, 5, 1}],
  {n, 1, N, 1}],
size],
{x, y}],
spin, {x, y}]
},
PlotRange -> PR, ImageSize -> IS, Background -> Black]
```

There are various parameters one could adjust here including some like x, y position and spin to rotate a snowflake which will be used later to animate snowfall.  Here is a sample of several snowflakes after fixing a particular choice of parameters and ranging Q to seed different random reals:

```
GraphicsGrid[
Table[
SnowFlake[Q*W, 0, 0, (-1)^(Round[rr[4 Q*W]]) (0 + rr[2 Q*W]) Pi/3, 1, 1,.85, .8, .5 + .2 rr[3 Q*W], 15, 2, 100],
{Q, 7, 13, 1}, {W, 14, 18, 1}], 
Background -> Black, ImageSize -> {500, 700}, AspectRatio -> 7/5]
```

[image: snowflake grid]

To generate snowfall, we parameter the x,y position, and spin of each snowflake with time t. I used the following code. Notice that Snowflake[] was used twice  and combined with Show[]. The reason this was done was to create a better simulation of depth in the snowfall. The only difference between the two is the size the snowflakes are allowed to randomly range through. Here, Q1 and Q2 can be varied to generate different snowflakes, and F1 and F2 control the number of snowflakes.

```
SF[Q1_, Q2_, F1_, F2_, t_] :=  Show[
Table[SnowFlake[
    Q1*f,
    4rr[2 Q1*f] - 2,
    1.25 - 2.5 (Mod[t + rr[3 Q1*f], 1]),
    (-1)^(Round[rr[4 Q1*f]])*t*Ceiling[6 rr[4 Q1*f]]*Pi/3,
    .04 + .03 rr[5 Q1*f],
    .8, 1, .3, .75, 6, {{-2, 2}, {-6/5, 6/5}}, {500, 300}],
   {f, 1, F1, 1}],
  Table[
   SnowFlake[
    Q2*f, 4 rr[2 Q2*f] - 2,
    1.25 - 2.5 (Mod[t + rr[3 Q2*f], 1]),
    (-1)^(Round[rr[4 Q2*f]])*t*Ceiling[6 rr[4 Q2*f]]*Pi/3,
    .07 + .12 rr[5 Q2*f],
    .8, 1, .3, .75, 6, {{-2, 2}, {-6/5, 6/5}}, {500, 300}],
   {f, 1, F2, 1}]
 ]

Export[
  "snowfall.gif",
  Table[
   SF[22, 40, 30, 15, t],
   {t, 0, 39/40, 1/40}]
  ]
```

[image: Animated Snowfall]

This animated gif loops seamlessly with 40 frames, but can of course be made smaller if desired. In my original project, I included some text (code not shown):

[image: Season's Greetings Snowfall]

Comment: In the future, when you create something nice know that you are welcome to post a (well written) question for the express purpose of sharing your "answer."

Answer (score 18):

This approach uses a voxel-based snowflake that actually looks quite realistic because of the way `Image3D` displays data. The set-up is similar to that of Simon, but everything is in 3D. So the calculations will be correspondingly more time-consuming.

```
flakyData = 
  ImageData[
   Dilation[
    RandomImage[BernoulliDistribution[0.0001], {150, 150, 150}], 
    DiskMatrix[{1, 1, 1}]]];

Image3D[flakyData]
```

[image: flakes]

With this, we now create an animation by rotating the data array downward:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 snowAnim = 
   Table[Rasterize[
     Show[Image3D[flakyData = RotateRight[flakyData, 3], 
       ColorFunction -> "BlackWhiteOpacity"], 
      Background -> Darker[Gray], ViewPoint -> Right, ViewAngle -> .6,
       Boxed -> False], "Image"],
    {i, 1, 50}];]

(* ==> {14.178811, Null} *)
```

So you have to wait several seconds for the frames to be generated. Here is the result:

```
Export["snowFall.gif", snowAnim, "DisplayDurations" -> .07, 
  "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity];
```

[image: snowFall]

By choosing the `ViewAngle` narrower than usual, the view of the `3D` box in which the flakes are falling doesn't include the empty space on the sides. But you could change that to make the appearance and disappearance of the snow flakes more noticeable. That would correspond to looking out into the night with a flashlight where you see the flakes only when they enter the beam...

If you're really patient, you can add some sideways wind as Rojo was suggesting in his `3D` solution, but here I would realize that with additional matrix rotations:

```
data = RandomInteger[BernoulliDistribution[0.0001], {150, 150, 150}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 snowAnim = 
   Table[Rasterize[
     Show[Dilation[
       Image3D[data = 
         MapIndexed[RotateRight[#, Floor[#2/30]] &, 
          RotateRight[data, 3]], 
        ColorFunction -> "BlackWhiteOpacity"], DiskMatrix[{1, 1, 1}]],
       Background -> Darker[Gray], ViewPoint -> Right, 
      ViewAngle -> .6, Boxed -> False], "Image"],
    {i, 1, 150}];]

(* ==> {142.734662, Null} *)
```

[image: snowStrom]

This is a snow storm. The reason why this takes so much longer to create is that I can't take the `Dilate` operation out of the `Table` because the `RotateRight` in different directions by different amounts will distort the flakes (unless they are single voxels). Maybe there's another way to speed this up, I just wanted to show what the `Image3D` approach looks like.

**Edit: making a GIF into a dynamic animated notebook display**

Since the question asked about `GIF` creation **and** `Dynamic` display, this is an opportunity to do both *combined*, with the `GIF` approach as described above as the first step.

The second step is now to re-import the `GIF` I just exported. For this, I have a general function that looks like this:

```
makeAnimation[list_, delayList_: {.03}] := 
 DynamicModule[{l = Length[list], delays = Abs@Flatten[{delayList}], 
   times, totalTime, delta = .03, frames},
  times = Round[.5 + PadRight[delays, l, delays]/delta];
  frames = 
   Flatten@Table[Table[list[[i]], {times[[i]]}], {i, Length[times]}];
  totalTime = Length[frames];
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic[frames[[Clock[{1, totalTime, 1}, totalTime delta]]], 
    TrackedSymbols -> {}], {"MouseUp", 2} :> Null
   ]
  ]

importGIF[fileName_] := Module[{lst, seq, pos, durations, frameList},
  lst = BinaryReadList[fileName];
  seq = FromDigits[#, 16] & /@ StringSplit["21 f9 04"];
  pos = Position[Partition[lst, 3, 1], seq];
  durations = (Extract[lst, pos + 4] + 256 Extract[lst, pos + 5])/
    100;
  frameList = Import[fileName];
  makeAnimation[frameList, durations]
  ]

importGIF["snowFall.gif"]
```

> `(* Same output as the first animation above, but now playing in notebook. *)`

The output cell can be copied anywhere you like, **even into a new notebook**. To reiterate: you only need to copy the output by selecting its *cell bracket*, *without* having to regenerate the movie by re-evaluating the input. So the function `importGIF` is the closest one can get to having the original `GIF` play in the *Mathematica* notebook the way it plays in a web browser.

An important ingredient in this function is actually not really used in this context: the ability to have a varying frame rate. This utilizes a solution by Heike to the question [When importing GIF animation, how to find the correct list of “DisplayDurations”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5361/245).

Answer (score 16):

My attempt adresses the second option. These are simple falling circles with random shift and color depending on the radius of the "snowflake".

```
snow[n_, {w_, h_}] := 
  DynamicModule[{flakes, cut, offset, drawflake, rmax, mgray = 0.85},
   rmax = w/100;
   drawflake = {GrayLevel[mgray + (1 - mgray) #2], Disk[#1, #2 rmax]} &;
   offset = cut @@ (#1 + 14 {#2 RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}], -#2}) &;
   cut = {#1~Mod~w, #2~Mod~h} &;
   flakes = Array[{{Random[] w, Random[] h}, Random[]} &, n]~SortBy~Last;
   Dynamic[
    Graphics[
     drawflake @@@ (flakes = {offset[#1, #2], #2} & @@@ flakes),
     Background -> LightGray,
     PlotRange -> {{0, w}, {0, h}},
     ImageSize -> {w, h},
     AspectRatio -> Automatic
     ]
    ]];
```

The usage is

```
snow[200, {800, 400}]
```

Here `200` is the number of snowflakes and `{800,400}` is the dimensions of the graphics.
The screenshot:
[image]

And finally a "full screen" version:

```
{{{z, fsw}, {z, fsh}}} = FullScreenArea /. (ScreenInformation /. 
    Options[$FrontEnd, ScreenInformation]);
CreateDocument[snow[200, {fsw, fsh}], WindowSize -> Full];
```

Comment: (+1) For FullScreenArea which I hadn't seen like this before. It works very nicely on my Mac... better than looking out at the rain that defines the winter here in Oregon, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

To animate snowflakes, we first need to create them. Here's a simple way to create snowflake-like objects:

```
makeLine = {Re@#, Im@#} &;
rot = Exp[I*Pi/3];
list = {0, 1, rot, rot^2, rot, 1, 1/rot, 1/rot^2, 1/rot^3, 1/rot^2, 
   1/rot, 1};
flake = Flatten@NestList[1/rot*# &, list, 7];
flakeprim = 
  Scale[Translate[Line[#], -Mean[#]], 1] &@
   Accumulate[makeLine /@ flake];
```

This uses the fact that multiplication by $\exp(i\phi)$   is a rotation by $\phi$ in the complex plane to successively rotate a straight line to create one arm of the flake, then rotating the whole thing a few times to create the whole flaks.

Here's how it looks:

```
Graphics[
    flakeprim,
    Axes -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Some* might say that this looks more like a spaceship than a snowflake. Maybe it does.

This may be animated using a minimal modification of faleichik's code (minimal means that I left everything alone except what I had to change, so bits are redundant):

```
snow[n_, {w_, h_}] := 
 DynamicModule[{flakes, cut, offset, drawflake, rmax, mgray = 0.85}, 
  rmax = w/100;
  drawflake = Scale[Translate[flakeprim, #1], #2] &;
  offset = cut @@ (#1 + 14 {#2 RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}], -#2}) &;
  cut = {#1~Mod~w, #2~Mod~h} &;
  flakes = 
   Array[{{Random[] w, Random[] h}, Random[]} &, n]~SortBy~Last;
  Dynamic[
   Graphics[
    drawflake @@@ (flakes = {offset[#1, #2], #2} & @@@ flakes), 
    Background -> LightGray, PlotRange -> {{0, w}, {0, h}}, 
    ImageSize -> {w, h}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]]
```

so eg

```
snow[30, {500, 500}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: now that I look at the animation again, it's more like falling dandelions than snowflakes...

Comment: Snowflakes have six-fold symmetry. If you use this fact , your animation would look more like snow.

Comment: @m_goldberg done! sadly, they still look more like dandelions than snowflakes...

Answer (score 10):

This could be a start for someone who wants to play around in v9

```
numFlakes = 400;
flake = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 0.3];
wind = {2, 1};
procs = Table[
   WienerProcess[\[Mu], 1], {\[Mu], {Sequence @@ wind, -3}}];
sampleTDs = 
  Table[RandomFunction[proc, {0, 20, 0.05}, numFlakes], {proc, procs}];
funs = With[{offset = {0, 0, 20} + {20, 20, 40} RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]}, 
     Function[time, Through@#[time] + offset]] & /@ 
   Transpose@Through@sampleTDs["PathFunction", All];
```

and then

```
Graphics3D[{Translate[flake, 
   Dynamic[With[{time = Clock[{0, 10, 0.05}]}, #@time & /@ funs]]]},  
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 Background -> LightGray, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {0, 20}}]
```

Comment: +1 for the 3D alone. Something weird, I see some half-open spheres sometimes.

Comment: @JoelKlein that's when they are half in the plot range. Many things to improve of this solution, I posted it as a start for others :)

Answer (score 10):

I created some (semi-random) snow for a Christmas related notebook I recently wrote. Thought it was worth sharing:

```
FallDown[Disk[{x_, y_}, r_]] := 
 Disk[{x + RandomReal[{-0.03, 0.05}], y - RandomReal[{0.05, 0.25}]}, r]
Snow[] := Module[{
   snowflakes = Disk[#, RandomReal[{0.03, 0.1}]] & /@
     Flatten[
      Table[{i + RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}], 
        j + RandomReal[{-0.3, 0.3}]}, {i, 0, 12}, {j, -5, 20}], 1],
   list = {}},
  Do[
   snowflakes = FallDown /@ snowflakes;
   AppendTo[list, Graphics[{White, snowflakes},
     PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}},
     Background -> Black]],
   {52}];
  list]
```

The final output of the notebook also adds some (again semi-randomly placed) trees and hills, along with Santa himself `:-)`

[image]

Comment: Did you create the Santa or is that an imported figure?

Comment: No, that's the only part I imported. I just split the image in Photoshop and imported the arm and body seperately.

Answer (score 9):

You may be wondering where all the snow seen in the brilliant and amazing answers above (assuming you've sorted answers by votes) ends up... The answer is, down here, on the floor. Sadly, I can't upload this riveting movie in its full unabridged splendour, although at least my cat enjoys watching the full 3-hour version.

This is how it starts:

[image: snow 1]

and here is the epic finale:

[image: snow 2]

```
flakes1 = 
  Table[Text[
    Style[FromCharacterCode[16^^2744], RandomInteger[{24, 30}], 
     White], {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}], {x, 3000}]; 
flakes2 = 
  Table[Text[
    Style[FromCharacterCode[16^^2746], RandomInteger[{24, 30}], 
     White], {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}], {x, 3000}] ;
flakes = Riffle[flakes1, flakes2];
t = Table[
   Graphics[
    {
     Opacity[0.8],
     flakes[[1 ;; x]]
     }, 
     Background -> Gray, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
   {x, 1, Length[flakes]}];
```

Comment: Time to turn on the windshield wiper.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the answer lies in generating snowflakes.

If one is truly interested in a random-generated snowflake, I suggest using varying initial conditions and rules for a 2D Cellular Automaton on a hexagonal grid to generate them.  A demonstration for this [already exists.](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SnowflakeLikePatterns/)