# Making a movie with specific frame-rate out of ListPlot outputs?

Tags: plotting, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to prerender animation in Wolfram Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/is-it-possible-to-prerender-animation-in-wolfram-mathematica)
>   [Does Mathematica support variable frame rate for any video format, in analogue of GIF-style “DisplayDurations”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/does-mathematica-support-variable-frame-rate-for-any-video-format-in-analogue-o)

I would like to make a movie that shows a series of `Plot`/`ListPlot` outputs as frames for `s` seconds of time each.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You might like to check out `Animate` and `ListAnimate`.

Comment: @image_doctor How would I output something like an AVI?

Comment: Is really somewhere explained how to create an AVI where every frame stays e.g. 3 seconds on screen??

Comment: @halirutan To answer your question: Another closely related Q/A is this: [Does Mathematica support variable frame rate for any video format, in analogue of GIF-style “DisplayDurations”?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4727/245)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have 50 frames already computed with `Plot`

```
expr = (1 - a) Exp[-x^2] + .5 a D[Exp[-x^2], x, x];
frames = Table[Plot[expr, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, 
  Filling -> Bottom], {a, 0, 1, 1/49}];
```

what you can do when exporting e.g. "AVI" files is setting the `"FrameRate"`. When you want to have for instance every frame displayed for 1 second the frame rate is 1 frame/second too. Unfortunately, this does only work for integer values and to have an image displayed for `s` seconds, you would have to set frame rate to `1/s`.
One bad hack is to set the frame rate to 1 and use several copies of the same frame. A better option here might be to use external tools. See for instance the link Jens gave in the comments

- [Does Mathematica support variable frame rate for any video format, in analogue of GIF-style “DisplayDurations”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4903/187)

A different thing is, when you use animated "GIF" files. There you can set the `"Duration"` of every frame which can be larger than one second and smaller too.

```
Export["movie.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: You've got a typo: it's `FrameDurations`, not `FrameDuration`. Without the `s` at the end, your exported movie doesn't actually have the duration you specified, but instead uses the default.

Comment: @Jens Thanks, I corrected my type (without using your Typo ;-) and now it works as expected.

Comment: Wow, it this a type of typo explosion?

Answer (score 0):

I might as well add another answer based on the variable frame rate `GIF` player contained in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16903/245):

```
exportMovie[movieName_String, list_, delayList_: {.03}] := 
 Module[{l = Length[list],
   delays = Abs@Flatten[{delayList}],
   times,
   totalTime,
   delta,
   frames},
  delta = Min[delays];
  times = Round[PadRight[delays, l, delays]/delta];
  frames = 
   Flatten@Table[Table[list[[i]], {times[[i]]}], {i, Length[times]}];
  Export[movieName, frames, "FrameRate" -> Round[1/delta]]
  ]
```

This takes a list of frames, e.g. the ones in halirutan's answer, and exports them **as a movie in `AVI` or `MOV` or similar formats**. These formats recognize the `"FrameRate"` option in `Export`, and you can calculate the desired frame rate as the reciprocal of the frame duration in seconds.

In this function, I generalized this to a *variable* frame rate by allowing an optional third argument that contains a **list** of individual frame durations.  If the list is shorter than the number of frames, it's repeated. To make certain frames in the list of the first argument appear longer, I simply replicate them a number of times depending on how much longer than the *minimum* duration in the list of the third argument is.

So with the example

```
expr = (1 - a) Exp[-x^2] + .5 a D[Exp[-x^2], x, x];
frames = Table[
   Plot[expr, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, 
    Filling -> Bottom], {a, 0, 1, 1/49}];
```

you would simply do

```
exportMovie["a.mov", frames, {.12}]
```

to get a movie where all frames have an *approximate* duration of `.12` seconds (there is rounding error).

The export format above is determined simply by the file name extension, so you could replace `.mov` by `.avi`.