# How to generate a random snowflake?

Tags: graphics, random, simulation, generative-art

'Tis the season...
And it's about time I posed my first question on Mathematica Stack Exchange.
So, here's an holiday quest for you Graphics (and P-Chem?) gurus.

What is your best code for generating a (random) snowflake in Mathematica?
By random I mean with different shapes that will mimic the diversity exhibited by *real* snowflakes.
Here's a link to have an idea: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~atomic/snowcrystals/ , more specifically here are the different types of snowflakes: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~atomic/snowcrystals/class/class.htm .

Physics-based answers are to be preferred, but graphics only solutions are also welcome.
There already is a thread on generating a snowfall, here: [How to create animated snowfall?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16881/how-to-create-animated-snowfall) and one of the posts addresses the problem of generating snowflake-like elements.
In the snowfall post, though, emphasis is on efficient generation of 'snowlike' *ensembles*. The purpose of this question (apart from having some 'seasonal' fun) is to create graphics that details the structure of a single snowflake. Efficiency is not the primary issue here: beauty is. A very detailed snowflake rendering could even take several minutes of computer power, thus making it unsuitable to incorporate into a snowfall simulation.

Here we are trying to generate a single snowflake (possibly with different parameters to tune its shape), the more *realistic*, the better.
Three dimensional renderings, for adding translucency and colors are also welcome. Unleash your fantasy, go beyond the usual fractals!

And if your fantasy is momentarily faltering, as Silvia pointed out in a comment below, on this website http://psoup.math.wisc.edu/Snowfakes.htm you can find a lot of information - and even a C program for the *Gravner-Griffeath 2D Snowfake Simulator* - on how to generate 'virtual snowflakes', even in 3D (have a look at the pdf files: "*Modeling Snow Crystal Growth*" I, II and III).

Comment: I don't want to kill the fun but.., did you see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/Fractals/KochSnowflake.nb)?

Comment: @Öskå, yes, I was aware of this method of generating snowflake-like fractals. And it is one welcome method, of course, but I wish to find more 'physically' oriented answers. Also, the more 'real-life', the better. (This is an holiday post, let's have some fun).

Comment: Nice fractal art here http://www.deviantart.com/morelikethis/317568361?offset=25#skins

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, [here](http://curriculum.makerbot.com/daily_lessons/january/koch.html) is a bit of code doing the job.

Comment: Anyone familiar with implementing [non-fractal solutions](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/ICE/small.pdf)?  This certainly seems possible in MMA.

Comment: @MichaelE2, never mind. I am about to incorporate the above comment in the question, then I'll remove the comment. Silvia appears to have killed the thread with her beatiful answer, but I still hope in  some other approach. I'll wait a bit before accepting the answer.

Comment: Yep, it's Christmas: miracles happen. :-)

Comment: Have you seen this [*Gravner-Griffeath Snowfakes*](http://psoup.math.wisc.edu/Snowfakes.htm)? I think they are kind of what you're looking for.

Comment: @Silvia, amazing! Yes, that's something I would love to see implemented in Mathematica. After all a great deal of the references in the first papers are on Wolfram's cellular automata articles. (Don't get me wrong, I really like your answer)

Comment: On Christmas day, this W `Integer` Wonderland post has 5 answers, 50 votes and 5 thousands views. It's fivelous! :-) I believe I will wait until New Year's day to accept an answer.

Comment: I really tried hard implementing them in MMA, but that is a lot of work. Most importantly, it needs massive computation, which is beyond my old PC's ability... Maybe you should put the link in your question and hope someone will do it :)

Comment: @Silvia, this is a fun post, it should not become 'work'. I have no practical need for such a code, I only hoped to collect here some code to produce visual marvels, something other people (and most notably all the younger minds that have now MMA for free on their RasPi) could use to embellish their season's greetings cards or simply to be amazed by the beauty of a snowflake, even if virtual or just something that looks like it (a snowfake as they call it). I will add link in my next edit. I am confident that sooner or later new implementations will be added. Yours is amazing.

Comment: When I said "work" I meant "fun" :P And yes there have been, and there will be more!:D

Comment: Random isn't random anymore. Did you know that snowflakes reation could be influenced by thoughts? Some experiments about inner feelings and ice formation are documented. See http://www.whatthebleep.com/water-crystals/ for a starting point.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

I did a very simple (in fact over-simple) snowflake simulator with `CellularAutomaton` years before. It's based on the hexagonal grid:

[image: hexagonal grid]

and range-1 rules:

[image: rule index]

### Initial code

First we'll need some functions to display our snowflakes:

```
Clear[vertexFunc]
vertexFunc = Compile[{{para, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{center, ratio},
    center = para[[1 ;; 2]];
    ratio = para[[3]];
    {Re[#], Im[#]} + {{1, -(1/2)},{0, Sqrt[3]/2}}.Reverse[{-1, 1} center + {3, 0}] & /@
                 (ratio 1/Sqrt[3] E^(I π/6) E^(I Range[6] π/3))
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   (*, CompilationTarget->"C"*)];

Clear[displayfunc]
displayfunc[array_, ratio_] := Graphics[{
   FaceForm[{ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][3]}],
   EdgeForm[{ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][4]}],
   Polygon[vertexFunc[Append[#, ratio]] & /@ Position[array, 1]]
   }, Background -> ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][0]]
```

### Main body

Consider 0/1 bistable states for every node on the hexagonal grid, where $0$ stands for empty nodes and $1$ stands for frozen nodes. Then, excluding all-zero case, there are 13 possible arrangements on the 6 vertices of a hexagon(those who are identical under rotation and reflection are considered as the same arrangement):

```
stateSet = Tuples[{0, 1}, 6] // Rest;
gatherTestFunc = Function[lst, Sort[RotateLeft[lst, # - 1] & /@ Flatten[Position[lst, 1]]]];    
stateClsSet = Sort /@ Gather[stateSet, gatherTestFunc[#1] == gatherTestFunc[#2] &];
stateClsSetHomogeneous = ArrayPad[#, {{0, 6 - Length@#}, {0, 0}}] & /@ stateClsSet;
```

And the simplest physical rule might be linking different arrangement to different probability of freezing(from $0$ to $1$) or melting(from $1$ to $0$).

[image: arrangements and probabilities]

Those 26 probabilities, `pFreeze` and `pMelt`, can be determined by some serious physical models, or can be chosen randomly just for fun. Then they can be used to establish rule function for `CellularAutomaton`:

```
Clear[ruleFunc2Comp]
ruleFunc2Comp = With[{
                      stateClsSetHomogeneous = stateClsSetHomogeneous,
                      seedSet = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, 1000],
                      pFreeze = {1, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 1, 0},
                      pMelt = {0, 0.7, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0}
                     },
   Compile[{{neighborarry, _Integer, 2}, {step, _Integer}},
           Module[{cv, neighborlst, cls, rand},
                  cv = neighborarry[[2, 2]];
                  neighborlst = {#[[1, 2]], #[[1, 3]], #[[2, 3]], #[[3, 2]], #[[3, 1]], #[[2, 1]]}&[neighborarry];           
                  If[Total[neighborlst] == 0, cv,           
                     cls = Position[stateClsSetHomogeneous, neighborlst][[1, 1]];           
                     SeedRandom[seedSet[[step + 1]]];           
                     rand = RandomReal[];               
                     Boole@If[cv== 0, rand < pFreeze[[cls]], rand > pMelt[[cls]]]           
                    ]           
                  ],           
           RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"(*,CompilationTarget -> "C"*)    
          ]
   ];
```

Apply `ruleFunc2Comp` on some initial state for some steps:

```
dataSet = Module[{rule,
                  initM = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 0},
                  rspec = {1, 1},
                  tmin = 0, tmax = 50, dt = 1
                 },
                 rule = {ruleFunc2Comp, {}, rspec};
                 CellularAutomaton[rule, initM, {{tmin, tmax, dt}}]
                ];
```

You can see how the snowflake grows:

```
Manipulate[
    Rotate[displayfunc[dataSet[[k]], .99], 90°],
    {k, 1, Length[dataSet], 1}]
```

[image: snowflake growing animetion]

### More snowflakes

Some other examples generated with different `pFreeze`, `pMelt` and `tmax`:

[image: more snowflakes]

Comment: This is fantastic! Also, this is the fastest I've seen an answer get to +10! Well done.

Comment: Now we're cooking!

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks. I somehow missed the last snowflake party, now here again! :D

Comment: @Peltio I only picked those parameters randomly. But there can be some really complex physical model. Like *The physics of snow crystals* by Kenneth G Libbrecht, Rep. Prog. Phys. 68 (2005) 855–895, etc.

Comment: Neat. I'm off to port your code to `R`...

Comment: @rm-rf Time for reddit?

Comment: @Silvia You could post an animated GIF of the manipulate to show the snowflake growing (for another +30 :) )

Comment: @belisarius I really failed to predict THIS amount of upvotes! :D

Comment: @Silvia I think this is by far not the end of the story, regarding upvotes :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'll try to make a GIF version to match the votes!

Comment: @belisarius You can cast your another +30 now! :)

Comment: @Silvia This st*pid site doesn't allow me :) Remember you can slow down the animation with the "DisplayDurations" option, if you want

Comment: @belisarius `Export["snowflake.gif", ...]` froze my computer.. I have to use a screen recorder to produce the GIF :(

Comment: There are a lot of free software packages like this one http://www.stone.com/GIFfun/GIFfun_Manual/Whirlgif_Man_1.html around that can generate an animated gif out of individual images, allowing  you to fine-control the animated output

Comment: @belisarius Slower does look much better. Thanks!:) And thanks for recommending a great site!

Comment: @Silvia One last trick: animations look much better if you run them first forward and then backward. Something like `i = 0; Export[
   "onegif" <> StringTake["00000" <> ToString[i++], -4] <> 
    ".GIF", #] & /@ Join[yourImageList, Reverse@yourImageList]`. By using something like it you get an animation that isn't "disrupted" at the end

Comment: @belisarius Thanks, I'll save this trick for next GIF! Today we see the flake *grow* :)

Comment: Just made an account to say that you guys are crazy.

Comment: Hey! You're now a 10K user! Welcome!

Comment: Joined because I had to give this a +1 - beautiful, but crazy at the same time.

Comment: @belisarius Hehe just found I can see some hiden posts now :)

Comment: This is great Silvia! I'd just change one thing

Comment: Prepend `inHotArgentinaQ[] := 
 Apply[And, {-40, -70} < FindGeoLocation[] < {-20, -55} // Thread]`. `If[inHotArgentinaQ[], 
 WolframAlpha[
  "image sun", {{"Image:AstronomicalData", 1}, "Content"}], #]&`

Comment: @Omega but not crazy enough to upvote?:P

Comment: @Rojo Hehe I like hot climate. Here in my town we can have 35 degrees Celsius in summer :) (OK maybe 35 is too hot :P

Comment: @Silvia 7PM and 37 Celsius right now, lots of people with no power, in a big city where for some reason every degree is felt like 10 (ok, maybe not so much)

Comment: Yet another that signed up just to upvote. This is nuts

Comment: @Rojo With no power that's not fun :( Sincerely wish it gets better...

Comment: Outstanding work in educational explanation and design! Where did you use this CA and what for? Was it just recreation?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov My past job was just some particular image processing and experimental data fitting, I did this CA snowflake because someday my friend asked for one and I thought it would be interesting. So yes I guess I can say it's just recreation :)

Comment: @Silvia is it possible to have restriction on the states ? for example not "creating" a state like p13 ? Setting pfreeze for that state to zero, and pmelt 1, stil creates states like p13. What am I missing here ?

Comment: @lalmei `p13` means *if the neighbors are 111111, then the center cell should become 1 with a probability of `p13`*, so the config of the neighbors is the cause not the effect. If you want to forbid some certain patterns, I think a quick way is to add a post-filter after each CA step.

Comment: @Silvia Yeah I think understand now. I tried forbidding some patterns after each step and just following what every other step is doing, but it works only so-so. I think this is against the spirit of cellular automata, but do you know if there is a way to see what the neighbourhood points are doing at the same step ?

Comment: @lalmei I think if you want more flexible control, you might consider a general network, like they did in neural network or finite element method. But I'm not sure about the efficiency..

Answer (score 81):

**========== update ===========**

Remember guys how we can cut out a snowflake from a sheet of paper carving 12th folded part? Like the image below.

[image]

So I decided to [**write an app**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/175200) to imitate the process. It also can be used to make random snowflakes (similar to to @bill s' but with reflection to imitate real cutting paper process and reflective symmetry of snowflakes). App and random collection are below.

```
snow[pt_] := Graphics[

  {EdgeForm[Directive[White, Opacity[.8]]],
   FaceForm[Directive[White, Opacity[.4]]],
   Polygon[
    Outer[#1.#2 &,
     Table[RotationMatrix[a], {a, 0, 2 Pi - Pi/3, Pi/3}],
     Join[Map[ReflectionMatrix[{1, 0}].# &, #], #] &@
      Join[{{0, 0}}, pt],
     1]]}

  , Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 100 {1, 1}]

Grid[Partition[ParallelTable[
   snow[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {RandomInteger[{3, 9}], 2}]],
   {64}], 8], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

This is [**preview of the app**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/175200):

[image]

**========== older versions ===========**

@Silvia did a beautiful job, especially at design and explanation. I still want to point out similar things with Cellular Automata (for the sake of a bit alternative implementation) and a bit different things in general.

1) Ed Pegg's Demo and related competition:

- [Snowflake-Like Patterns](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SnowflakeLikePatterns/)
- [Two Hundred Thousand Snowflake Greetings to You and Yours](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/28/two-hundred-thousand-snowflake-greetings-to-you-and-yours/)

[image]

2) Spinoff of Herbert W. Franke: [Parametric Snowflake Design](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParametricSnowflakeDesign/)

[image]

3) Croucher & Weisstein's [n-Flakes](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NFlakes/)

[image]

4) Some awesome Koch's:

- [Create Alternative Koch Snowflakes](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CreateAlternativeKochSnowflakes/)
- [Fractal Curves](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FractalCurves/)

[image]

5) [Some more](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=Snowflake)

As Mr. Wizzard asked in the answer I am including the (modified) code for 2) due to its simplicity and beauty:

```
x1[a_, b_, c_, t_] :=  Sin[.5 t] - a Sin[b t]*Cos[t] - .1 c Sin[10 b t];
y1[a_, b_, c_, t_] :=  Cos[.5 t] - a Sin[b t]*Sin[t] - .1 c Cos[10 b t]; 

GraphicsGrid[Partition[ParallelTable[
   With[{
     a = RandomReal[{-1.5, 1.5}],
     b = RandomInteger[{3, 15}],
     c = RandomReal[{0, 1.5}],
     clr1 = Black,
     clr2 = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3],
     clr3 = RGBColor @@ RandomReal[1, 3],
     thick = RandomReal[{.04, .5}],
     tm = 1}, 
    ParametricPlot[
     Evaluate[{{x1[a, b, c, t], y1[a, b, c, t]}, {x1[a, b, c, t], 
        y1[a, b, c, t]}}], {t, 0, tm 4 \[Pi]}, 
     PlotStyle -> {{clr2, Thickness[0.001` + 0.05` thick]}, {clr3, 
        Thickness[0.001` + 0.01` thick]}}, Axes -> False, 
     PlotPoints -> 200, PlotRange -> All, Background -> clr1]]
   , {n, 32}], 4], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Here come the votes. :-)

Comment: Would you consider including your favorite code in this post so that if the links go dead it is still an answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done ;-)

Comment: Wow, the parametric method is GREAT!

Comment: Thanks @Silvia your solution is very beautiful too.

Comment: some of those remind me of snowflakes i've seen on other planets. ah the memories

Answer (score 32):

Here is a simple method that begins with an $n$-sided polygon (defined by the $n$ points in `tab`), then rotates the polygon and superimposes it six times to achieve the six-fold symmetry. The `makeFlake` function is:

```
makeFlake[n_] := Module[{tab, rot},
  tab = RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2}, {n, 2}];
  rot = RotationMatrix[Pi/3]; 
  Graphics[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Opacity[RandomReal[{0.3, 0.6}]], 
    Polygon[tab.MatrixPower[rot, #]] & /@ Range[6]}, Background -> Black]]
```

Some sample output:

```
GraphicsGrid[Table[makeFlake[16], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]]
```

[image]

For more complex shapes, increase the value of `n`, which is the number of sides of each polygon. Here are some examples with `n=32`.

[image]

If, for some reason you think that snowflakes ought to be white, change `Hue[RandomReal[]]` to `White`:

[image]

Update: It is also simple to "color" the polygon using an image. For example, using a snow-filled winter scene as a texture in the polygons:

```
thisImg = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMCN1.jpg"];
poly[img_, x_] := {Opacity[RandomReal[{0.5, 0.8}]], EdgeForm[], 
   Texture[img], Polygon[x, VertexTextureCoordinates -> x]};
makeFlakeImage[img_, n_] := Module[{},
   tab = RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2}, {n, 2}];
   rot = RotationMatrix[Pi/3, {0, 0, 1}];
   Graphics[Rotate[poly[img, tab], #, {0, 0}] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/3]]];

GraphicsGrid[Table[makeFlakeImage[thisImg, 10], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The frosty feel from images is so wintery! Nice!

Comment: Beautiful fragile gems!

Answer (score 27):

Not so much snowflakes as random artworks with the same symmetry as snowflakes, but I wanted to join in the festive fun! These are generated with a "randomart" package I wrote a while ago (code at the bottom of the answer). It uses a kind of non-linear iterated function system to generate random images.

Here's a grid of random images with snowflake symmetry:

```
Table[randomart[100, RandomInteger[{1, 4}], Conjugate, 6], {5}, {5}] // Grid
```

[image]

If you specify a larger image size the code will do more iterations to give more detail. Here are a couple at 400 x 400 pixels:

```
randomart[400, RandomInteger[{1, 4}], Conjugate, 6]
```

[image]
[image]

Here's the package code:

```
BeginPackage["randomart`"];
randomart::usage = 
  "randomart[size, n, sym, m] produces a random image. size is the \
image size. n is the number of individual patterns to compose \
together. sym is a symmetry function to apply (the points making up \
the image are represented as complex numbers, so for example use \
Conjugate to obtain left-right symmetry). To apply no symmetry \
function use {}. If supplied, m will cause the image to be created \
with m seed points evenly distributed around the unit circle, leading \
to m-fold rotational symmetry in the final image. For more 'organic' \
results use no symmetry function and omit m (or set to zero).
  Large sizes will be expensive in time and memory, 500 is a good size.
  randomart[size] will produce an image with random parameters.
  Results are a bit hit & miss - be prepared to generate several \
images to find a nice one. ";
Begin["`Private`"];
gradients = {x, x^2, Sqrt[x], 1 - x, (1 - x)^2, 1 - x^2, Sqrt[1 - x], 
   1 - Sqrt[1 - x], x (2 - x), Abs[-1 + 2 x], 1 - Abs[-1 + 2 x], 
   4 x (1 - x), Sqrt[Abs[-1 + 2 x]], 1 - Sqrt[Abs[-1 + 2 x]]};
hsbfunc := 
  Module[{h1, h2, ff}, h1 = RandomReal[]; 
   h2 = h1 + 0.5 RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
   ff = {h1 (1 - x) + (h2) x}~Join~RandomChoice[gradients, 2];
   Function @@ Hold[x, Evaluate[ff]]];
rc := Sqrt[#1] Exp[2 Pi I #2] & @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2];
parameters[m_] := 
  Module[{n, points, r1, r2, z1, z2, z3}, 
   If[m == 0, n = RandomInteger[{3, 12}]; points = Table[rc, {n}], 
    n = m; points = RandomReal[{0, 1}] Exp[2. I Pi Range[n]/n]];
   r1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
   r2 = RandomChoice[{1, 2} -> {r1, Abs[rc]}];
   z1 = RandomChoice[{1, rc, Abs[rc]}];
   z2 = RandomChoice[{2, 1} -> {z1, rc}];
   z3 = Exp[I RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]];
   {n, points, r1, r2, z1, z2, z3}];
binlog = Compile[{{q, _Real, 2}, {size, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{x, qr, qi}, x = ConstantArray[1, {size, size}];
    {qr, qi} = 1 + Floor[(size - 1) q];
    Do[x[[qr[[j]], qi[[j]]]] += 1, {j, Length[qr]}];
    N[Log[x]]], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
rawimage[{n_, points_, r1_, r2_, z1_, z2_, z3_}, size_, sym_] := 
  Module[{c, data, q}, 
   c = Compile[{{x, _Complex, 1}}, 
     Evaluate[Abs[z1 - z3 x]^r1 Exp[I r2 Arg[z2 - z3 x]] points], 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
   data = Flatten@Nest[c, points, Floor[Log[12 size^2]/Log[n]] - 1];
   q = process[data, sym];
   GaussianFilter[Clip[1.5 Rescale[binlog[q, size]], {0, 1}], 2]];
process[data_, sym_] := 
  Module[{dat, q}, dat = If[sym === {}, data, data~Join~sym[data]];
   q = Rescale[{Re[dat], Im[dat]}];
   If[sym === {}, q, centre[q]]];
centre[q_] := q + (0.5 - 0.5 (Max[#] + Min[#]) & /@ q);
prettify[pic_] := 
  Module[{i}, 
   i = Image[Re[hsbfunc[pic]], Interleaving -> False, 
     ColorSpace -> "HSB"];
   ImagePad[ColorConvert[Image[i, Interleaving -> True], "RGB"], 
    Round[Length[pic]/23], Automatic]];
oneframe[size_, sym_, m_] := 
  prettify@rawimage[parameters[m], size, sym];
alpha[image_] := Module[{a}, a = ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"];
   If[PixelValue[a, {1, 1}] > 0.5, a = ColorNegate@a];
   SetAlphaChannel[image, a]];
compose[n_, size_, sym_, m_] := 
  Fold[ImageCompose, oneframe[size, sym, m], 
   Table[alpha@oneframe[size, sym, m], {n - 1}]];
randomart[size_, n_, sym_: {}, m_: 0] := 
  ImageResize[compose[n, Round[69/50 size], sym, m], Scaled[2/3]];
randomart[size_] := 
  randomart[size, RandomInteger[{1, 4}], 
   RandomChoice[{2, 1} -> {{}, Conjugate}], 0];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Comment: +1 Love the idea of iteration, great as usual!

Answer (score 24):

Well I guess one more couldn't hurt. Using an iterated matrix-replacement scheme and some fancy opacity:

```
powzerz = 2;
width = 550;
primitive = Scale[Cuboid[], 0.99999];
matrix0 = {{{1}}};
matrixT = CrossMatrix[{1, 1, 1}];
rules = {0 -> (0 #1 &), 1 -> (#1 &)};

iterate[matrix0_, matrixT_, rules_, power_] :=
    Nest[Function[prev,
        ArrayFlatten[Map[#[prev] &,
            Replace[matrixT, rules, {3}], {3}], 3]],
      matrix0, power];

g = With[{objects = Translate[primitive, Position[iterate[matrix0, matrixT, rules, powzerz], 1]]},
   Graphics3D[{White, Opacity[.9], EdgeForm[None], objects},
    Lighting -> "Neutral", Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, ImageSize -> 4 width,
    Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> 2000 {1, 1, 1}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, Background -> Black]];

ImageResize[Rasterize[g], Scaled[1/4]]~ImagePad~20
```

[image]

It's a simple 3D cross fractal (this code is a reduced version of [this monster](http://www.oftenpaper.net/flipbook-matrixreplacement3D1.htm)). Although it's 3D, you get 2D figures. In this case Koch outlines. I wonder what kinds of 2D hex systems you could describe in terms of 3D, and vice-versa (e.g. an automaton rule on a 3D grid which is perspectivally equivalent to an automaton rule on a hex lattice).

For no reason, a bright cotton candy version:

```
powzerz = 4;
width = 550;
primitive = Sphere[.5 {1, 1, 1}];
matrix0 = {{{1}}};
matrixT = CrossMatrix[{1, 1, 1}];
rules = {0 -> (0 #1 &), 1 -> (#1 &)};

iterate[matrix0_, matrixT_, rules_, power_] :=
    Nest[Function[prev,
        ArrayFlatten[Map[#[prev] &,
            Replace[matrixT, rules, {3}], {3}], 3]],
      matrix0, power];

g = With[{objects = Translate[primitive, Position[iterate[matrix0, matrixT, rules, powzerz], 1]]},
   Graphics3D[{White, Opacity[.95], Glow[Blue], Specularity[Darker@Red], EdgeForm[None], objects},
    Lighting -> "Neutral", Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, ImageSize -> 4 width,
    Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> 2000 {1, 1, 1}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, Background -> Black]];

ImageResize[Rasterize[g], Scaled[1/4]]~ImagePad~20
```

[image]

Comment: i just noticed this isn't particularly in line with what OP was looking for. i don't think it'll hurt anyone though and it's in the Christmas spirit

Comment: +1 at least it looks a bit like a snowflake - half the images on this page are just wannabe hexagons... :)

Comment: The OP said in the comments: "I hoped to collect here some code to produce visual marvels... to embellish season's greetings cards.. even if virtual or just something that looks like a snowfake." Almost all the answers fit this description!

Answer (score 21):

Here is an un-golfed and simplified version of an [L-System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) production based on a previous answer of mine:

```
f1[initState_, rotAngle_, prodRules_, iters_] :=
 Module[{currAngle = 0, currPos = {0, 0}, res = {}},
  (res = {res, Line@{currPos, currPos += {Cos@currAngle, Sin@currAngle}}};
          If[NumericQ@#, currAngle += I^# rotAngle]) & /@ 
                                                Nest[Flatten[# /. prodRules] &, initState, iters];
  Graphics@Flatten@res
  ]
```

Used to produce a [Koch Snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) (not random, just fractal):

```
f1[{C[1], 2, 2, C[1], 2, 2, C[1], 2, 2, C[1], 2, 2, C[1]}, 
    Pi/4, {C[1] -> {C[1], 4, C[1], 2, 2, C[1], 4, C[1]}}, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Usage instructions and original golfed version [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9351/315).

Answer (score 20):

A smooth changing fractal snowflake:

```
{s, d, t} = {0, 1, 3};
Dynamic@Graphics@
  Polygon@Reap[
     If[# != 0, t += 8.^-5; 
        Do[#0[# - 1]; 
         Sow[d = Sign@d #; {Re[s += d], Im@s}] & /@ (# E^(I t #) &@ 
           Range@6/(5^(4 - #))); d *= E^((\[Pi] - 63 t)/3 I), {6}]] &@
      3][[2, 1]]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to fix the image size... I almost got a headache from watching it! :)

Answer (score 4):

For couple of years I was thinking that I should post an answer here using the [`RandomMandala`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomMandala) framework.

So, finally (after some experimentation) I got *reasonable enough* snowflakes.

**Remark:** The code of this answer produces snowflake images that resemble the snowflakes of both [Silvia's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39368/34008) and [Vitaliy's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39380/34008).

**Remark:** The "main idea" is also described in more detail [my answer of "How to add doodles and sketches in a mandala"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267098/34008).

---

### Code

```mathematica
Clear[TwigSeed];
Options[TwigSeed] = {"ShiftOffset" -> 0.3, "ShiftFactor" -> 1/3, 
   "ShiftRange" -> {0.5, 2}, "Inversions" -> 2};
TwigSeed[radius_, angle_, n_Integer : 5, args___, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{shiftOffset, shiftFactor, shiftRange, inversions, t, p, ps, 
    ps2, fs, inds},
   
   shiftOffset = OptionValue[TwigSeed, "ShiftOffset"];
   shiftFactor = OptionValue[TwigSeed, "ShiftFactor"];
   shiftRange = OptionValue[TwigSeed, "ShiftRange"];
   inversions = OptionValue[TwigSeed, "Inversions"];
   
   ps = {#, 0} & /@ Rest[Range[0, 1, 1/n]]; 
   ps = Map[RandomReal[{0.95, 1.05}]*# &, ps];
   ps2 = Map[#[[1]]*{Cos[angle], Sin[angle]} &, ps];
   
   fs = Sort@
     MapThread[
      Norm[(#2 - #1)]*shiftOffset + 
        shiftFactor*RandomReal[shiftRange] &, {ps, ps2}];
   Which[
    IntegerQ[inversions],
    Do[
     inds = RandomChoice[Range@Length@fs, 2];
     fs = ReplacePart[fs, Thread[inds -> fs[[Reverse[inds]]]]],
     {i, inversions}
     ],
    
    MemberQ[{Random, RandomSample}, inversions],
    fs = RandomSample[fs],
    
    MemberQ[{Reverse, ReverseSort}, inversions],
    fs = ReverseSort@fs
    ];
   
   t = MapThread[{#1, #1 + (#2 - #1)/
          Norm[(#2 - #1)]*#3} &, {{1 - #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ 
       ps, {1 - #[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ ps2, fs}];
   t = Map[{AbsoluteThickness[RandomReal[{2, 5}]], Line[#]} &, t];
   t = Prepend[
     t, {AbsoluteThickness[RandomReal[{4, 7}]], 
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}];
   
   (*GeometricTransformation[t,ScalingTransform[{radius,radius}]]
   *)t
   ];
```

```mathematica
Clear[Snowflake];
Snowflake[blurQ_ : True, effectQ_ : True] := Block[{gr, img},
   gr = ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"][
     "RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> RandomChoice[{8, 2} -> {6, {6, 3}}],
      "SymmetricSeed" -> True, 
     "SeedFunction" -> (TwigSeed[##, 
         "ShiftOffset" -> RandomReal[{0.2, 0.6}], 
         "ShiftFactor" -> RandomReal[{0.2, 0.6}], 
         "ShiftRange" -> {0.2, 0.9}, 
         "Inversions" -> 
          RandomChoice[{6, 2, 2} -> {2, None, Random}]] &), 
     "NumberOfSeedElements" -> RandomInteger[{4, 12}], 
     ImageSize -> 400, ImageMargins -> {30, 30}, 
     ColorFunction -> (Black &)];
   
   img = ImagePad[ColorNegate@Image[gr], 30];
   
   If[TrueQ[blurQ],
    img = Blur[Dilation[img, RandomReal[{2, 4}]], 4]
    ];
   
   If[TrueQ[effectQ],
    img = 
     ImageEffect[
      ImageEffect[
       img, {"Jitter", 
        Max[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[6, 3]], 
         1]}], {"OilPainting", RandomInteger[{2, 6}]}]
    ];
   
   img
   ];
```

---

### Without additional image effects

```mathematica
SeedRandom[11];
Multicolumn[ParallelTable[Snowflake[True, False], 40], 8, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

---

### With additional image effects

```mathematica
SeedRandom[11];
Multicolumn[ParallelTable[Snowflake[True, True], 40], 8, Background -> Black]
```

[image]