# How to optimally solve and generalize this Conway's Game of Life puzzle

Tags: list-manipulation, cellular-automata, game

I tried solving [this](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/how-long-can-life-last-in-this-simulation/?group=pEGCLArvO2ws) using mma. I am aware of
this command - **Cellular automata**. 
But i don't want to use that coz then there is no challenge.
So below is how i did it and my question is can this be done with fewer lines of code (without resorting to *CellularAutomaton*). Also i wanted to generalize it to any initial condition.

> I am representing the grid shown in the puzzle as a (n $\times$ m) matrix such that all the live cells are represented by *1* and the dead ones by *0*. Also  in this particular case we have $n = 26$ and $m = 27$.
>   Then i manually made a list of the initial condition given in the question. Here each pair represents the $(ij)^{th}$ element having live cells.
>
> - *[as a side note - can this process be automated - i mean finding this list from that image given for the intial grid by some image processing]*

```
list = {{2, 6}, {2, 13}, {3, 23}, {3, 25}, {4, 3}, {4, 10},
       {4, 9}, {4, 18}, {5, 18}, {5, 2}, {8, 11}, {8, 12},
        {10, 10}, {10, 12}, {11, 11}, {12, 18}, {13, 2}, {14, 2}, {13, 
         23}, {14, 8}, {14, 23}, {16, 24}, {17, 25}, {18, 24},
          {18, 18}, {18, 17}, {19, 12}, {20, 12}, {20, 3}, {20, 4}, {22, 
        24}, {23, 23}, {22, 17}, {23, 18}};
```

> The matrix $A_{n \times m}$ now contains the elements *1* and *0* corresponding to the live and dead cells receptively.
>   
>  
>   $f^{ij}_{0}$ contains the $(ij)^{th}$ element of $A_{n \times m}$

```
  A[n_, m_] := SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ list, {n, m}, 0]

 Table[f[0][i, j] = A[26, 27][[i, j]], {i, 1, 26}, {j, 1, 27}];
```

> The recursive function which gives the next generation is:-

```
f[k_][i_, j_] := f[k][i, j] = Module[{n = 26, m = 27, neg},

  findNeighbours[i, j] := Module[{},
     f[k - 1][#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{i - 1, j - 1}, {i - 1, 
       j}, {i - 1, j + 1}, {i, j - 1}, {i, j + 1}, {i + 1, 
         j - 1}, {i + 1, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}}];

   neg = Cases[findNeighbours[i, j], _Integer];

    (* Apply the rules to the ij th element*)
    Which[f[k - 1][i, j] == 1,
          Which[Count[neg, 1] < 2, 
          val = 0, (Count[neg, 1] === 2 || Count[neg, 1] === 3), val = 1, 
           Count[neg, 1] > 3, val = 0],
            f[k - 1][i, j] == 0,
            Which[Count[neg, 1] === 3, val = 1, True, val = 0]]

       ]
```

> Finally we can plot the results to see the answer which is 3 if the starting generation is called $1^{st}$ generation.

```
   genaration[0] = 
     ArrayPlot[
    Table[f[0][i, j] = A[26, 27][[i, j]], {i, 1, 26}, {j, 1, 27}], Mesh -> True];


   genaration[n_] := 
     ArrayPlot[Table[f[n][i, j], {i, 1, 26}, {j, 1, 27}], Mesh -> True]

  res = ListAnimate[genaration[#] & /@ Range[0, 3], 
         AnimationRate -> 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: Related http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/9393/longest-non-repeating-game-of-life-sequence

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My "Game of Life" implementation:

```
a = RandomInteger[BernoulliDistribution[0.1], {200, 200}];

Dynamic[Image[a =
   1 - Unitize[(# - 3) (# - 12) (# - 13)] &@
    ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 10, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, a, {2, 2}, 0]
  ]]
```

[image]

To use the initial grid in the question you would just initialise `a` with:

```
a = SparseArray[list -> 1]
```

However my code continuously updates the grid (quite rapidly), so the grid evolves to the "all dead" state in a fraction of a second.

To actually answer the question "how many generations have any life in them" you could write the evolution step as a function and use [`FixedPointList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FixedPointList.html) to count the number of steps:

```
evolve[a_] := 1 - Unitize[(# - 3) (# - 12) (# - 13)] &@
  ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 10, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, a, {2, 2}, 0]

Length@FixedPointList[evolve, Normal[SparseArray[list -> 1]]] - 2
(* 3 *)
```

Note that `FixedPointList` will generate the complete list of grids, so for larger problems you would want to use a different approach to avoid eating all your computer's memory.

Comment: honestly i really don't understand this fully. care to put some comments. like how would i implement this for the initial grid as given in the puzzle.

Answer (score 9):

This is one way of implementing *Conway's Game of Life*:

```
step[matrix_] := Module[{m = matrix, neighbours},
  neighbours = ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, ArrayPad[m, 1]];
  m = ReplacePart[m, Position[neighbours, _?(# == 1 || # > 3 &)] -> 0];
  m = ReplacePart[m, Position[neighbours, 3] -> 1]
  ]
```

For example, this is the so called glider:

```
m = ArrayPad[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {1, 10}];
ListAnimate[ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> True] & /@ NestList[step, m, 30]]
```

[image: glider]

I've written about another cellular automata problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39793/can-you-apply-the-cellular-automata-function-to-a-grid-containing-numbers/39863#39863) and this includes [a link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/137758) to a post where image processing was used in *Mathematica* to get initial states for a cellular automata problem, so the answer to that question is that yes it is possible.

Comment: really liked the way ListConvolve is used. such a powerful command. Thanks