# Open a pop up window that runs a calculation in loop until it is closed?

Tags: syntax, infinite-loop

How should I construct a code which opens a pop up window, displays a constantly updating image in it and is terminated once the pop up is closed? The constant updating would be an infinite loop of predefined functionality. Is this possible in Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Simon's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42135/193)

```
CreateDialog[
 {(a = RandomInteger[BernoulliDistribution[0.1], {200, 200}];
   Dynamic[ Image[a = 1 - Unitize[(# - 3) (# - 12) (# - 13)] &@
                     ListConvolve[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 10, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, a, {2, 2}, 0]]]), 
   DefaultButton[]}, Modal -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow, this looks cool. I wonder how the speed of evolution gets set since no `Pause[]` is used?

Comment: @Kagaratsch I believe the actual display and the calculation are decoupled. In any case you may try to see how many FPS your system is capable of :D

Comment: Or post a question about that :D

Comment: Ok, let me edit the above question in order to specifically ask for a dynamic pop up involving the `Pause[]` command.

Comment: @Kagaratsch Changing your question scope _after_ you receive answers is a bad practice, I think

Comment: Ok, I will put it as a new question!