# Simulation of diffusion in a grid

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, simulation

I want to simulate a diffusive process in a 2D grid, for a central initial value of 1 to the adjacent cells initially at 0.

At each time step, the value of the +1 level adjacent cells are increased by a definite value (normalized to be maximum 1). I chose a decreasing exponential function but other types of functions could fit.

t=0

```
00000
00000
00100
00000
00000
```

t=1

```
00000
0xxx0
0x1x0
0xxx0
00000
```

t=2

```
yyyyy
yzzzy
yz1zy
yzzzy
yyyyy
```

etc.

I looked for other related questions but couldn't find any similar except for this one, which is a bit different though: [Can you apply the Cellular Automata function to a grid containing numbers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39793/can-you-apply-the-cellular-automata-function-to-a-grid-containing-numbers)

For now I'm struggling with For loops and counters but I'm not satisfied with my solution.

Thank you in advance for your tips.

Comment: You can use `ListConvolve` to do convolution of your 2D grid with a diffusion kernel to simulate a single time step.

Comment: I recommend the books "Modeling Nature" by Gaylord and Nishidate, as well as "Computer Simulations with Mathematica" by Gaylord and Wellin.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `ListConvolve` to simulate a single diffusion time step and build a simulation out of that. I'll show a simple example: Let's say we start with simple initial conditions like in your example

```
(initialconditions = Normal@SparseArray[{{3, 3} -> 1}, {5, 5}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: initial conditions]

and a diffusion kernel

```
kernel = {
  {1/120, 1/60, 1/120},
  {1/60, 9/10, 1/60},
  {1/120, 1/60, 1/120}
};
```

Then we can define a function that simulates a single time step as

```
Step = ListConvolve[kernel, #, 2, 0] &;
```

Here the `2` aligns with the center of our kernel to make sure the simulation  doesn't drift. The `0` is for padding outside our kernel, otherwise we would get cyclic convolution which we don't want in this case.

Now we can simulate multiple time steps via `NestList`:

```
solution = NestList[Step, initialconditions, 30];
```

and plot the solution as an animation:

```
ListAnimate[ListPlot3D[#, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}] & /@ solution]
```

[image: animated diffusion plot]

## Realistic thermal diffusion example

We can do a more realistic example to show how we could actually use this to simulate a real physical scenario.

We'll start with the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Statement_of_the_equation)

```
heateq = dudt - \[Alpha] laplaceu == 0
```

where `u` is the temperature, $\alpha$ is the [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity), `dudt` is the change of temperature over time, and `laplaceu` is the curvature of the temperature, i.e. the total of the second derivatives of `u` with respect to our spatial dimensions `x` and `y`.

Let's discretize our heat equation in time by replacing our time derivative by a finite difference

```
heateq /. {dudt -> \[CapitalDelta]u/\[CapitalDelta]t}
```

now, we can solve this for $\Delta u$ to know what our next u after one timestep should be

```
nextu = u + \[CapitalDelta]u /. First@Solve[%, \[CapitalDelta]u]
```

> u + laplaceu $\alpha$ $\Delta$t

The next step is to discretize our heat equation in space, too. We do this by approximating our spatial derivatives by [finite difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Explicit_method) approximations, which requires the value of the immediate neighbours for every grid cell for which a 3x3 kernel is sufficient. The kernel can be constructed like this:

```
(diffusionkernel = nextu /. {u -> ( {
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0}
   } ), laplaceu -> (1/\[CapitalDelta]x^2 ( {
       {0, 0, 0},
       {1, -2, 1},
       {0, 0, 0}
      } ) + 1/\[CapitalDelta]y^2 ( {
       {0, 1, 0},
       {0, -2, 0},
       {0, 1, 0}
      } ))}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Inputting the diffusion kernel]

[image: Diffusion kernel matrix]

and now we have a nice general diffusion kernel where we can plug in physical values for the width and height of our grid cells, the thermal diffusivity of our material and the amount of time one simulated time step represents.

For this example let's go with 1mm x 1mm grid cells and a time step of 1ms and Gold, which has a [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity) of $1.27\cdot10^{-4} m^2/s$

```
kernel = diffusionkernel /. {
             \[Alpha] -> 1.27*10^-4(*thermal diffusivity of gold*),
             \[CapitalDelta]x -> 1/1000(*1mm*),
             \[CapitalDelta]y -> 1/1000(*1mm*), 
             \[CapitalDelta]t -> 1/1000(*1ms*)
         }
```

[image: Specific diffusion kernel with numeric values]

We define our diffusion step as before

```
DiffusionStep = ListConvolve[kernel, #, 2, 0] &
```

and choose a grid dimension to represent 1cm x 1cm

```
n = 11;(* set the dimensions of our simulation grid *)
```

We need some initial conditions

```
(initialconditions = Array[20 &, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

representing constant room temperature of 20 degrees. Also we need some interesting boundary conditions. Let's say we choose to heat the left half of the border of our gold bar to a constant 100 degrees and the right side we cool to have constant 0 degrees:

```
(bcmask = Array[Boole[#1 == 1 \[Or] #1 == n \[Or] #2 == 1 \[Or] #2 == n] &, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
(bcvalues = Array[If[#2 <= n/2, 100, 0] &, {n, n}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: boundary condition mask][image: boundary condition values]

Here we encoded the boundary conditions as a binary mask, which specifies if the grid cell is a boundary cell and a matrix which contains the values the boundary cells should have.

We can now write a step which enforces our boundary condition:

```
EnforceBoundaryConditions = bcmask*bcvalues + (1 - bcmask) # &;
```

E.g. applied to our initial conditions it looks like this

```
EnforceBoundaryConditions[initialconditions] // MatrixForm
```

[image: example of our applied boundary conditions]

Now that we have everything together we can start our simulation of our partly heated/partly cooled infinite 1cm x 1cm gold bar!

```
solution = NestList[
               Composition[EnforceBoundaryConditions, DiffusionStep], 
               initialconditions,
               30
          ];
```

and visualize the result:

```
anim = ListPlot3D[#2,
           PlotRange -> {0, 100}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
           AxesLabel -> {"x/mm", "y/mm", "T/\[Degree]C"}, 
           PlotLabel -> "Temperature distribution after " <> ToString[#1] <> " ms", 
           DataRange -> {{0, n - 1}, {0, n - 1}}
       ] & @@@ Transpose[{Range[Length[#]] - 1, #} &@solution];
ListAnimate[anim]
```

[image: Gold heat diffusion sim with boundary conditions.]

This was actually fun working on, thanks to @J.M. for the suggestion!

Comment: That animation is mesmerizing. I'm not an expert, so: where did `kernel` come from?

Comment: Thanks! To be honest i just made it up :) the most important thing is that it's symmetric, and if you want energy (heat/mass/etc) conservation the components should add up to 1. For something physically accurate it's probably a good idea to discretize a kernel like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel) by integrating it for individual grid cells and using that.

Comment: Another way would be discretizing the differential operator itself (in this case the laplace operator), as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator) and using it in the original [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) to get a time step update recipe for our grid.

Comment: If you ever have time to spare, could you do an animation with a realistic kernel? :)

Comment: WOW! Thank you for following through! I will study this carefully.

Comment: You're welcome! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Also for reference, a great source for getting a more in depth look at these kinds of hands on engineering examples is the book 'Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers' by Stanley Farlow, published by Dover. Can highly recommend that book.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I finally did it with traditional programming tools but this helps a lot to have a second Mathematica optimized code.

Comment: @Valacar, if you came up with your own *Mathematica* implementation, I would suggest that you post it as another answer to your own question. We may be able to offer tips on your code.

Comment: @J.M. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

**My personal answer**:

There is my personal (traditional programming style) interpretation of my problem.

Let's say we have a grid of 50*50, with 1 representing a possibility of occupation and 0 an impossibility (ex: water in a valley with hills, where it can't go).

```
x0 = 50;
y0 = 50;
Table[Table[tab0[i, j] = 1, {j, 1, y0}], {i, 1, x0}];
```

I created two variables with the same size of the grid, one representing the concentration (`Cpop`) and the other a counter (`compteur`).

```
Clear[Cpop, compteur]
MatrixForm[Table[Table[Cpop[i, j][0] = 0, {j, 1, y0}], {i, 1, x0}]];
MatrixForm[Table[Table[compteur[i, j][0] = 1, {j, 1, y0}], {i, 1, x0}]];
Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0] = 1;
compteur[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0] = 3;
```

The idea is that at the beginning we have a drop at the center of the grid, which diffuses following a concentration function `conc[t]` (no matter its form). The counter has 3 values: 1, 2 or 3. Then I coded multiple conditions with changing counter values. If the counter is 3 I skip it, etc.

```
For[t = 1, t < 50, t++,
 For[i = 1, i <= x0, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= y0, j++,
Cpop[i, j][t] = Cpop[i, j][t - 1];
compteur[i, j][t] = compteur[i, j][t - 1]
 ]
];

For[i = 1, i <= x0, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= y0, j++,
  If[Cpop[i, j][t] > 0 && compteur[i, j][t] == 3,
   If[compteur[i - 1, j - 1][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i - 1, j - 1][t] = 
  conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0] ; 
 compteur[i - 1, j - 1][t] = 2];
   If[compteur[i - 1, j][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i - 1, j][t] = conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0]; 
 compteur[i - 1, j][t] = 2];
   If[compteur[i - 1, j + 1][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i - 1, j + 1][t] = 
  conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0] ; 
 compteur[i - 1, j + 1][t] = 2];
   If[compteur[i, j - 1][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i, j - 1][t] = conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0] ; 
 compteur[i, j - 1][t] = 2];
   If[compteur[i + 1, j - 1][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i + 1, j - 1][t] = 
  conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0] ; 
 compteur[i + 1, j - 1][t] = 2];
   If[compteur[i + 1, j][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i + 1, j][t] = conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0] ; 
 compteur[i + 1, j][t] = 2];
   If[compteur[i + 1, j + 1][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i + 1, j + 1][t] = 
  conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0]; 
 compteur[i + 1, j + 1][t] = 2];
   If[compteur[i, j + 1][t] != 3, 
 Cpop[i, j + 1][t] = conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0]; 
 compteur[i, j + 1][t] = 2];
Cpop[i, j][t] += conc[t] Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][0];
  ]
 ]
];

For[i = 1, i <= x0, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= y0, j++,
 Cpop[i, j][t] = Cpop[i, j][t] tab0[i, j];
 If[compteur[i, j][t] == 2,
  compteur[i, j][t] = 3
  ]
 ]
];

Cpop[Round[x0/2], Round[y0/2]][t] = 1;
]
```

With that code (not that elegant though), I managed to observe interesting phenomena. For example, let's imagine a grid with an obstacle (like a river crossed by a bridge).

[image: After 10 iterations]

[image: After ~15 iterations]