# Function representing a forest fire after one time step

Tags: functions, matrix, iterators, cellular-automata

How can I create a function that would have as its argument an array mat of 0s, 1s, and 2s where the 2s are burning trees and the function would give an array that represents the forest after one time step?

I have tried using

```
mat=RandomChoice[{0,1,2},{10,10}]
nextstep[mat_]:=Sequence[mat2 + {1, 0}, mat2 + {0, 1}, mat2 + {-1, 0}, mat2 + {0,-1}]
```

but that doesn't seem to work. After one time step, every tree, represented by 1s, that is in the von Neumann neighborhood of a burning tree would catch fire, but the 0s, which means there are no trees, would remain the same.

EDIT: How can I further develop this so as to have a function that has as its argument the array mat and can iterate nextstep, until the array doesn't change anymore? So, essentially this new function would return `{mat, nextstep[mat], nextstep[nextstep[mat]],...}`. I tried using `finalstate[mat_]:=NestList[nextstep, mat, 5]`, but it's not returning what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39793)?

Comment: Yes I have seen it and I tried to construct my function from some of those answers, but I was still finding it difficult to do so @J.M.

Comment: For what it's worth, you might have a look at "level set methods" and in particular "fast marching" as a more general but related approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example. First we need some data:

```
n = 5;
mat = RandomChoice[{0, 1, 2}, {n, n}];
```

Then we need a function that shifts a list to the left or right, filling the empty place with zeros. It is nearly the same functionality as RotateRight/Left, but we do not want it to be circular. Therefore we set the elements that are circulated to zero.

```
shiftr[m_] := Prepend[Rest[RotateRight[m]], 0 m[[1]]]
shiftl[m_] := Append[Most[RotateLeft[m]], 0 m[[1]]]
```

We define now a step: With the help of `shiftr/l` we shift the current matrix left/right/up/down and take the maximum at every position, that gives a matrix `mat1` with 2 at all the shifted positions of 2's. Finally we imprint this shifted 2's onto the the matrix `mat`:

```
step[mat_] := (mat1 = 
    MapThread[
     Max, {shiftr[mat], shiftl[mat], shiftr /@ mat, shiftl /@ mat}, 
     2]; MapThread[If[#2 == 2, 2, #1] &, {mat, mat1}, 2]);
```

Now we apply this to our data:

```
mat // MatrixForm
(mat = step[mat]) // MatrixForm
(mat = step[mat]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way of doing this but the 0s dont become 2s after one step? @DanielHuber

Comment: Sure, simply change `step`to: `step[mat_] := (mat1 = 
    MapThread[
     Max, {shiftr[mat], shiftl[mat], shiftr /@ mat, shiftl /@ mat}, 
     2]; MapThread[If[#2 == 2 && #1 == 1, 2, #1] &, {mat, mat1}, 2]);`

Comment: and then if i used something like NestList, could i potentially iterate this function, or matrix, until all the 1s become 2s? @DanielHuber

Comment: Yes, that's the idea,

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[vNNeighbors, nextStep]
vNNeighbors[dim_] := AdjacencyList[NearestNeighborGraph @ Tuples @ Range @ dim, #]&

nextStep = MapAt[Min[2, 2 #] &, #, vNNeighbors[Dimensions @ #][Position[#, 2]]] &;
```

***Example :***

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomChoice[{0, 1, 2}, {10, 10}];

Row[MapThread[Labeled[#, #2, Top] &, 
   {MatrixForm /@ {mat /. 2 -> Highlighted[2], 
      nextStep[mat] /. 2 -> Highlighted[2, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]}, 
   {Style["mat" , 16], Style["nextStep[mat]", 16]}}], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Use `nextStep` with `NestList` to simulate spreading of `2`s in the initial matrix `mat`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomChoice[{49, 50, 1} -> {0, 1, 2}, {40, 40}];

timesteps = 60;

frames = MatrixPlot[# /. {0 -> White, 1 -> Green, 2 -> Red}, Mesh -> All, 
    ImageSize -> 400] & /@ NestList[nextStep, mat, timesteps];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Nearest` to find the neighbors of a list of indices. This approach is more flexible in that we can use the option `DistanceFunction` to consider alternative definitions of *neighbors*.

```
ClearAll[nF, NN, nextStep]
nF[dims_, df_: Automatic] := Nearest[Tuples @ Range @ dims, DistanceFunction -> df]

NN[mat_, val_, df_: Automatic] := Join @@
  nF[Dimensions @ mat, df][Position[mat, val], {All, 1}]

nextStep[df_: Automatic] := MapAt[Min[2, 2 #] &, #, NN[#, 2, df]] &;
```

Default distance function `Automatic` (`"EuclideanDistance"`) gives von Neumann neighbors and `"ChessboardDistance"` gives Moore neighbors.

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomChoice[{0, 1, 2}, {10, 10}];

Row[MapThread[Labeled[#, #2, Top] &, {MatrixForm /@ 
    {mat /. 2 -> Highlighted[2], 
     nextStep[][mat] /. 2 -> Highlighted[2, Background -> Red], 
     nextStep["ChessboardDistance"][mat] /. 
          2 -> Highlighted[2, Background -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]}, 
   {Style["mat", 16], Style["nextStep[][mat]", 16], 
    Style["nextStep[\"ChessboardDistance\"][mat]", 16]}}], Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomChoice[{49, 50, 1} -> {0, 1, 2}, {40, 40}];

timesteps = 60;

frames1 = MatrixPlot[# /. {0 -> White, 1 -> Green, 2 -> Red}, Mesh -> All, 
     ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> False, 
     PlotLabel -> Style["EuclideanDistance", 16]] & /@ 
   NestList[nextStep[], mat, timesteps];

frames2 = MatrixPlot[# /. {0 -> White, 1 -> Green, 2 -> Purple}, Mesh -> All, 
     ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> False, 
     PlotLabel -> Style["ChessboardDistance", 16]] & /@ 
   NestList[nextStep["ChessboardDistance"], mat, timesteps];

frames = Row /@ Transpose[{frames1, frames2}];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]