# How to generate Koch curve in mathematica

Tags: graphics

How is done in Mathematica to generate the curve? Exists in the fractal geometry Koch curve, consisting of partitioning a line segment of lngitud 1 in three equal parts, by removing the central part and replaced by an isosceles triangle whose sides are the same length as the length of the extracted segment.

Comment: You find the answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39367/187) and [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9351). I vote to close this as dublicate.

Comment: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Oct/msg00062.html