# How to add doodles and sketches in a mandala

Tags: machine-learning, wolfram-cloud, scripting, education, generative-art

i discovered mathematica yesterday; and i've been playing with `RandomMandala` since.
i also saw this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136974/code-that-generates-a-mandala); and i really liked the second answer; but i like the change the "feeling" of it; maybe remove the circles and add a heart or something. can someone point me to a tutorial or help me understand how i can edit this?.
i tried changing the "flower layer" but i couldn't make anything new; instead i made something with the same pattern.

edit: this is what i did so far

1 - `RandomMandala` : i changed the options on the "neat example"

```
SeedRandom["make a living tonight"]; Multicolumn[
 Table[ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"][
   "Radius" -> Reverse[Range[RandomChoice[{3, 4, 5, 6}]]], "NumberOfSeedElements" -> RandomChoice[{25, 26, 30}], "RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> RandomChoice[{20, 21, 15, 39, 7}], ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", "ConnectingFunction" -> FilledCurve@*BezierCurve, "SymmetricSeed" -> True, FaceForm -> {Opacity[0.7]}, EdgeForm -> {LightBlue, Opacity[1]}, ImageSize -> 150], 10], 6]
```

this is the result
[image]

2 - i also tried this code found the on the question above

```
flower[n_, a_, r_] := Module[{b = RandomChoice[{-1/(2 n), 0}]},
  Cases[ParametricPlot[
   r (a + Cos[n t])/(a + 1) {Cos[t + b Sin[2 n t]], Sin[t + b Sin[2 n t]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
   l_Line :> FilledCurve[l], -1]]

disk[_, _, r_] := Disk[{0, 0}, r]

spots[n_, a_, r_] := Translate[Disk[{0, 0}, r a/(4 n)], r CirclePoints[n]]

mandala[n_, m_] := Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], White, Table[
    RandomChoice[{3, 2, 1} -> {flower, disk, spots}][n, 
      RandomReal[{3, 5}], i]~Rotate~(Pi i/n), {i, m, 1, -1}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All]

GraphicsGrid[Table[mandala[16, 20], {2}, {2}]]
```

and the results were actually good just by changing the seed number.

BUT i want to make more like these
[image]
[image]

i think that it can be done with mathematica; by just finding the "right" function.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include the copy-paste-able Mathematica code that you have tried out so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer

> i think that it can be done with mathematica; by just finding the "right" function.

Yes, and you have found the right function. ([`RandomMandala`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomMandala) from the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/).)

In short, any doodles you want to use have to be expressed in terms of graphics primitives and be put within a seed generation function. (With a signature that fits the `RandomMandala` framework.)

For example, using doodles produced with the code:

```
(BezierCurve@RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, #1, {0, #2}], 9] &) // Graphics[{Thick, #[1, \[Pi]/4]}] &
```

[image]

we can make make mandalas seeded by them through the option "SeedFunction":

```
SeedRandom[12];
Table[ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"][
 "RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> RandomChoice[{3, 6, 12}],
 "SeedFunction" -> (BezierCurve@RandomPoint[Disk[{0, 0}, #1, {0, #2}], 9] &)], 
5]
```

[image]

Below I show how to use fragments of images in the mandala making process.

#### Procedure outline

Here is an outline of the procedure we follow below:

- Transform one of the given images and extract its components
- Convert the components into point coordinates and rescale them to be within $[0,1]$
- Make mandala seed function with arguments `radius` and `angle`:*

  - Selects points to be within the unit disc sector that corresponds $[0, angle]$
  - Scales the selected points with `radius`
  - Makes `Graphics` points
- Plot mandalas of with the defined mandala seed function

#### Code and walk-through

First let us transform one of the given images and extract its components:

```
img1d = Dilation[EdgeDetect[img1], 0.6];
mcs1 = MorphologicalComponents[Thinning[img1d], 0.01];
Colorize@mcs1
```

[image]

Here is an association for each component with its corresponding points:

```
aCompCoords = Association[# -> Position[mcs1, #] & /@ Rest[Union[Flatten[mcs1]]]];
Length[aCompCoords]
Length /@ aCompCoords

(*30*)

(*<|1 -> 24462, 2 -> 168, 3 -> 158, 4 -> 161, 5 -> 73, 6 -> 73, 7 -> 156, 8 -> 69, 9 -> 66, 10 -> 163, 11 -> 68, 12 -> 102, 13 -> 63,14 -> 63, 15 -> 149, 16 -> 157, 17 -> 160, 18 -> 159, 19 -> 72, 20 -> 63, 21 -> 74, 22 -> 156, 23 -> 159, 24 -> 69, 25 -> 65, 26 -> 158, 27 -> 73, 28 -> 72, 29 -> 163, 30 -> 164|>*)
```

Rescale the obtained point coordinates:

```
aCompCoords2 = AssociationThread[Keys[aCompCoords], Values[aCompCoords] /. {x_?NumberQ :> Rescale[x, {ImageDimensions[img1][[1]]/2, ImageDimensions[img1][[1]]}, {0, 1}]}];
```

**Remark:** I prefer to use direct rescaling instead of using `GeometricTransformation` and `ScalingTransform` because computations are faster and the data is "readily" interpretable.

Here we define the mandala seed generating function that uses extracted graphical elements of the given mandala image:

```
Clear[MandalaImageSegment]
Options[MandalaImageSegment] = {"ComponentCoordinates" -> aCompCoords2, "MaxComponentSize" -> 30000, "ShowLargeComponents" -> False};
MandalaImageSegment[radius_, angle_, args___, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Block[{reg, regf, aCompCoords, aCompCoordsIn, maxSize, showLargeOnes}, 
    showLargeOnes = TrueQ[OptionValue[MandalaImageSegment, "ShowLargeComponents"]]; 
    maxSize = OptionValue[MandalaImageSegment, "MaxComponentSize"]; 
    aCompCoords = OptionValue[MandalaImageSegment, "ComponentCoordinates"]; 
    reg = Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, angle}]; 
    regf = RegionMember[reg]; 
    aCompCoordsIn = Map[Pick[#, regf[#]] & /@ # &, aCompCoords]; 
    aCompCoordsIn = radius*aCompCoordsIn; 
    If[showLargeOnes, 
     {Map[Point, Values[Select[aCompCoordsIn, Length[#] <= maxSize &]]], {PointSize[0.005], Opacity[0.2], Map[Point, Values[Select[aCompCoordsIn, Length[#] > maxSize &]]]}}, 
    (*ELSE*) 
     {PointSize[0.005], Opacity[0.8], Map[Point, Values[Select[aCompCoordsIn, Length[#] <= maxSize &]]]} 
    ] 
   ];
```

Here is how the seed segment looks like for the angle $\pi /6$:

```
Graphics[MandalaImageSegment[1, \[Pi]/6, "ComponentCoordinates" -> N[aCompCoords2], "MaxComponentSize" -> 500, "ShowLargeComponents" -> True], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Finally, here are mandalas with the defined mandala seed function:

```
Grid@Table[
   ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"]["Radius" -> 10, "RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> rs, "SeedFunction" -> (MandalaImageSegment[##, "MaxComponentSize" -> 500, "ShowLargeComponents" -> show] &), PlotLabel -> rs], {show, {False, True}}, {rs, {5, 6, 4}}]
```

[image]

Here is a multi-mandala mode example:

```
SeedRandom[33];
ResourceFunction["RandomMandala"]["Radius" -> {10, 10}, "RotationalSymmetryOrder" -> {12, 6}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", "SeedFunction" -> (MandalaImageSegment[##, "MaxComponentSize" -> 2000, "ShowLargeComponents" -> False] &)]
```

[image]