# How can I combine my 3D graphics and animate them?

Tags: animation

I'm just a beginner but can someone tell me how I can take my image of an Elf and put it together with a 3d background and I'm trying to animate it snowing but I wanna use a "play" button. Trying to do a short ten second one. Any ideas?

```
Import["http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/woHs5kFd3dI/maxresdefault.jpg"]

Graphics3D[{Red, Cone[],
  White, Sphere[{0, 0, -1.5}, 1.03],
  Red, Sphere[{0, 0, -3}, 1.09],
  Red, Sphere[{1, 0, -2.8}, 1/4], 
  Sphere[{1.4, 0, -2.85}, 1/4.5],
  Sphere[{1.7, 0, -2.95}, 1/4.9], 
  Sphere[{-1, 0, -2.8}, 1/4],
  Sphere[{-1.4, 0, -2.85}, 1/4.5], 
  Sphere[{-1.7, 0, -2.95}, 1/4.9],
  Yellow, Sphere[{1.9, 0, -3.1}, 1/5.3],
  Sphere[{-1.9, 0, -3.1}, 1/5.3], 
  Black, Sphere[{-.5, -.80, -1.2}, 1/6], 
  Sphere[{.5, -.80, -1.2}, 1/6], Black, 
  Sphere[{-.3, -.84, -1.8}, 1/9],
  Sphere[{.3, -.84, -1.8}, 1/9], 
  Sphere[{.15, -.84, -1.9}, 1/9],
  Sphere[{-.15, -.84, -1.9}, 1/9], 
  Sphere[{0, -.84, -1.92}, 1/9],
  Green, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .457], 
  Green, Sphere[{0, 0, -.5}, .68],
  Green, Sphere[{0, 0, -1}, .901], 
  Sphere[{0, 0, 1}, 1/6],
  Green, Sphere[{0, 0, .5}, .235], 
  Sphere[{0, -1, -3}, 1/7],
  Green, Sphere[{0, -.87, -2.5}, 1/7], 
  Green, Sphere[{0, -.87, -3.5}, 1/7],
  White, Sphere[{.9, 0, -1.5}, 1/4],
  Sphere[{-.9, 0, -1.5}, 1/4]}]

Graphics3D[{Translate[flake, 
  Dynamic[With[{time = Clock[{0, 10, .05}]}, #@time & /@ funs]]]}, 
  Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  Background -> LightBlue, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {0, 20}}
```

Comment: Here is a related question that may give you some ideas: [How to create animated snowfall?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16881/245)

Comment: It seems that you shouldn't be using `Dynamic` because that's overkill (in fact, the last command is incomplete because `funs` is undefined). If you want a play button, you could use `ListAnimate[frames]` - where `frames` is the list of frames...

Comment: What should I use instead of dynamics? I want to keep it very simple

Comment: I've put some of the ingredients into my answer - not including the snowfall, which you may want to do yourself because there are so many ways - you have to see which of the answers in the linked Q&A you like best... But my answer shows how `ListAnimate` works.

Answer (score 11):

What you're trying to do requires several ingredients.

First, you want to define your elf so that it can be combined with other objects in a `Graphics3D` scene. This means you would just define the primitives making up the elf as follows:

```
elf = {Red, Cone[], White, Sphere[{0, 0, -1.5}, 1.03], Red, 
   Sphere[{0, 0, -3}, 1.09], Red, Sphere[{1, 0, -2.8}, 1/4], 
   Sphere[{1.4, 0, -2.85}, 1/4.5], Sphere[{1.7, 0, -2.95}, 1/4.9], 
   Sphere[{-1, 0, -2.8}, 1/4], Sphere[{-1.4, 0, -2.85}, 1/4.5], 
   Sphere[{-1.7, 0, -2.95}, 1/4.9], Yellow, 
   Sphere[{1.9, 0, -3.1}, 1/5.3], Sphere[{-1.9, 0, -3.1}, 1/5.3], 
   Black, Sphere[{-.5, -.80, -1.2}, 1/6], 
   Sphere[{.5, -.80, -1.2}, 1/6], Black, 
   Sphere[{-.3, -.84, -1.8}, 1/9], Sphere[{.3, -.84, -1.8}, 1/9], 
   Sphere[{.15, -.84, -1.9}, 1/9], Sphere[{-.15, -.84, -1.9}, 1/9], 
   Sphere[{0, -.84, -1.92}, 1/9], Green, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, .457], 
   Green, Sphere[{0, 0, -.5}, .68], Green, Sphere[{0, 0, -1}, .901], 
   Sphere[{0, 0, 1}, 1/6], Green, Sphere[{0, 0, .5}, .235], 
   Sphere[{0, -1, -3}, 1/7], Green, Sphere[{0, -.87, -2.5}, 1/7], 
   Green, Sphere[{0, -.87, -3.5}, 1/7], White, 
   Sphere[{.9, 0, -1.5}, 1/4], Sphere[{-.9, 0, -1.5}, 1/4]};
```

Then you want a 2D image to be included in the `Graphics3D` scene. This can be done with the following convenience function, which takes the image (or other object) as its first argument `s`, and then places it with its upper left corner at 3D coordinate `pos`. The orientation of the upper edge coming out of that corner is defined by the next argument `xVec`. Also, the *length* of `xVec` is equal to the length of the horizontal axis with which your image will be displayed, in units of the 3D scene. So by making `xVec` longer, you scale up the whole image proportionally. The vertical edge of the image is tilted with respect to the vertical axis of the `Graphics3D` scene by an angle `tiltAngle` (it;s not needed here, so I set it to `0`):

```
pic3D[s_, pos_, xVec_, tiltAngle_] := 
  Module[{width, height, r}, 
   r = Rasterize[Style[HoldForm[s], Magnification -> 10], "Image"];
   {width, height} = ImageDimensions[r];
   Translate[(* //to make lefthand corner pos*)
    Rotate[(*   //around z axis*)
     Rotate[(* //around y axis*)
      Rotate[(* //tilt around x axis*)
       Scale[(*//to make width equal|
        xVec|*){EdgeForm[], Texture[ImageData@r],(* //
         Texture fills polygon initially in the xz plane*)
         Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {width, 0, 0}, {width, 0, height}, {0, 0,
             height}}, 
          VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
             1}}]}, Norm[xVec]/width, {0, 0, 0}], 
       tiltAngle, {1, 0, 0}],(* //x rotation*)
      Arg[Chop@N[Norm[xVec[[1 ;; 2]] + I xVec[[3]]]]], {0, -1, 
       0}],(* //y rotation*)
     Arg[Chop@N[xVec[[1]] + I xVec[[2]]]], {0, 0, 1}],(* //z rotation*)
    pos]];
```

Now I'll combine the two objects defined above

```
pic = Import["http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/woHs5kFd3dI/maxresdefault.jpg"];
frames = Table[
   Rasterize[
    Graphics3D[{Rotate[elf, angle, {0, 0, 1}], Glow[White], 
      pic3D[pic, {-7, 5, -5}, {14, 0, 0}, 0]}, Boxed -> False , 
     SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> {0, -10, -.5},
     ViewAngle -> .05,
     ImageSize -> {360, 200}],
    "Image"],
   {angle, 0, 2 Pi - Pi/10, Pi/10}];
```

Here I use `Table` to generate the frames where the angle of rotation of the elf is varied. In order to make the background image appear with its own "natural" color, I added the `Glow[White]` before inserting it with `pic3D[pic,...]` at a position that looks OK.

**Edit:** To improve the rendering in the animation, I added some steps in the above `Table`: First, reduce the `ViewAngle` and add an `ImageSize` option to `Graphics3D` so that the displayed region better matches the aspect ratio of the scene.  Second, wrap each `Graphics3D` frame in `Rasterize[..., "Image"]` because this dramatically speeds up the subsequent `ListAnimate`. The animation then looks a little better that the `GIF` I uploaded (but I'll just leave the old `GIF` up for now).

Now make the animation. Unfortunately *Mathematica* is not very fast at rendering 3D graphics, so even the generation of the `ListAnimate` display will take some time.

```
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: elf]

To create the gif, I did this:

```
Export["elf.gif", frames, "DisplayDurations" -> .07, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

Clearly, the quality could be improved, but I just want to show some basic steps.

Comment: Forgot to say THANKS! GREATLY APPRECIATE IT!