# Christmas fun with Mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics, code-generation

In a previous [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16881/how-to-create-animated-snowfall) we saw how we can create animated snowfall. So, I was wandering what else, related to Christmas, we can do with Mathematica? Perhaps, drawing a tree full of ornaments and lights...

All ideas are welcome! I suppose it would be nice to have a post full of nice codes related to Christmas.

Comment: **too broad** *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: We could try and create a fractal Christmas tree!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree. Would it be appropriate, or let's say acceptable, as a CW, big-list type Q&A? Maybe if it's closed as OT, it could be reopened as CW....Just random thoughts.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing groundbreaking, but a quick composure of some graphics objects:

```
tree = Graphics[{Darker@Darker@Green, 
   Triangle[{{0, 1}, {4, 1}, {2, 6}}], Darker@Brown, 
   Rectangle[{1.7, 0}, {2.3, 1}], Yellow, 
   Rectangle[{.6, .25}, {1.5, .9}], Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, .75}], 
   Rectangle[{2.1, .2}, {3, .9}], Blue, 
   Rectangle[{1.2, -.1}, {2.2, .5}], Purple, 
   Rectangle[{2.7, 0}, {4, .7}], Yellow, 
   Point@RandomPoint[Triangle[{{0, 1}, {4, 1}, {2, 6}}], 80]}]
```

[image: tree]