# Applying Some Kind of Timing Function to AutoRunSequence

Tags: manipulate, video, automation

Ok, so I'm exporting a video to MOV format that is coming from a manipulate function (I'm demonstrating CLT to a class that doesn't have calculus as a pre-req, if anyone is curious).  Anyhow, I'm mostly happy with it, but ideally I'd like it to not generate the frames of the video linearly, but rather spend more frames on the front section and decrease as it approaches the max boundary.  Is this possible?  This is the current code:

```
manr = Manipulate[
   Resample = Table[Mean[RandomChoice[SetAll, Length[SetAll]]], {Samples}];
   Histogram[Resample, Axes -> {False, False}, ImageSize -> Large], {Samples, 100, 100000}, 
   AutorunSequencing -> {Automatic, 30}];
Export["~/desktop/sam.mov", manr]
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4727/5

Comment: You can control the rate another way, with something like `Bookmarks -> MapIndexed[#2 :> (Samples = #) &, Range[10, 310, 20]^2]` or set the way points explicitly.  If bookmarks are present, `Export` interpolates between them instead of using `Autorun`.  So put more way points in the beginning.  I can't give a full answer because the question has been closed as a duplicate.  To use that answer you'll have to have to make a table/list of histograms, instead of your `Manipulate`, of course.

Comment: Also, the CLT depends on the sample size, not how many samples you take from the sampling distribution of a given sample size.  Your code has the samples all the same size `Length[SetAll]`.  Of course you'll need a large number of samples, so that the empirical distribution shown in the histogram approximates the actual sampling distribution well.