# Outputting a film (in .avi, .mp4, etc. formats) where frames correspond to Graphics3D outputs

Tags: export, graphics3d

I'd like to make a exportable film (in some format like .avi or .mp4, something playable on most computers) where each frame is a Graphics3D output.  For example, we might generate frames in the following way:

```
polytopeSize = 3;

numFrames = 10;  
frameSet = Table[Graphics3D[Table[Translate[Scale[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "Faces"], polytopeSize], RandomReal[{0, 5}, 3]], {i, 1, 5}]], {k, 1, numFrames}];
```

I'd like to be able to set a time delay individually for each frame:

```
frameSetTimeDelaysInSeconds = RandomReal[{0,1}, numFrames];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/does-mathematica-support-variable-frame-rate-for-any-video-format-in-analogue-o) for a solution for non-GIF files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea that could be worth exploring:

```
table = Flatten[
  MapThread[
    Table[#1, {Round@#2}] &, {frameSet, 30 * frameSetTimeDelaysInSeconds}]];

Export["frameset.mov", table]
```

This just duplicates frames for as many times as necessary - inelegant, I suppose, but it might do.

Answer (score 0):

The hyperlink from cormullion is cormullion is ideal.

A table of "DisplayDurations" can be used for animated gifs.

AVI's tend to be very large and you can use other software to compress.
MOV/QT files are reasonable.

Here is away to have variable frame durations by padding frames:

```
framerate = 15;
framnum = Round[framerate frameSetTimeDelaysInSeconds]
film = Join @@ MapThread[Table[#1, {#2}] &, {frameSet, framnum}];
```

You can then export:

```
Export["yourfilename.avi", film,"FrameRate" -> framerate]
```

This will be a large file.

For quicktime:

```
Export["yourfilename.mov", film,  "FrameRate" -> framerate]
```

I note the default frame rate for quicktime is 15fps...I just illustrate potential to change (play with).

An example is [here](https://app.box.com/s/t0v6w7tv0oal2bmb3e12)