# How to make the animation rate lower in an exported GIF

Tags: export

I have a ".gif" figure exported from the following codes. 6 separated figures (frames) constitute a ".gif" figure.   But the default time interval between each  frame is less than 1 second.  I hope to increase the time interval to 3 seconds, so the speed can be lower. Any one can help me?  Thank you all in advance!

```
g1[a_, b_] := Graphics[{Red, Disk[{a, 0}, 1], Green, Disk[{1, 1}, 1], Blue, Disk[{b, 2}, 1]}];
f1 = Table[Show[g1[a, b] , PlotRange -> {{-2, 12}, {-2, 4}}  ], {a, 1, 8, 4}, {b, 0, 10, 5}];
f1 = Flatten[f1]
Export["f1.gif", f1]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Export["f1.gif", f1, "DisplayDurations" -> (# of seconds)]`

Comment: Also, `"DisplayDurations"` can be a list of time values, one for each individual frame. Ironically, this is a feature that `GIF` export offers whereas you can't do it easily for standard movie formats: see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4727/245).

Comment: This can be found in the documentation under [GIF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/GIF.html).

Comment: Many thanks to mfvonh,  Jens and Rahul, this option really works.

Comment: Look under Options on [this Documentation Center page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/GIF.html).
Also note this item from the same page: 'With the default setting "DisplayDurations"-> Automatic, the display time will vary on different viewer applications'.

Comment: or here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29485/5478

Comment: I don't think this is correctly marked as a duplicate:  They both are related questions, but the [first link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/does-mathematica-support-variable-frame-rate-for-any-video-format-in-analogue-o) doesn't even have an answer for this question, and the [second link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27202/how-to-export-this-animation-as-a-gif-file-for-powerpoint-presentation) you have to scroll down to the third answer.

Comment: (continued) This is the primary google search result for "mathematica gif frame rate" so I think the first comment here should be converted to an answer.

Comment: I've reopened. Anybody up for writing a canonical answer, then?

Comment: @J.M. I've posted something -

Answer (score 18):

Although this is an old question, I'll post an answer:

The delay between frames (in seconds) can be controlled with the option `"DisplayDurations"`. If it's a single number, then that's the delay between all the frames of the exported gif animation.

Another thing you can do is to provide a `List` as follows:

```
Export["f2.gif", f1, "DisplayDurations" -> {.1, 1}]

(* ==> "f2.gif" *)
```

[image: gif]

Here you see a fast-slow step combination because the list of durations `{.1, 1}` is repeated cyclically for successive frames.