# How to dynamically name and date a file for export?

Tags: export, text, excel

I have various functions that export Excel and text files, and need to have them named with a name based on the content of some variables in the function and the time and date.  How can this be done with Mathematica?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the [answer linked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1147/245), I did the following:

```
out = FileNameJoin @ {$TemporaryDirectory, "MathematicaOutput" <> ToString /@ Date[] <> ".rtf"}
```

> `/tmp/MathematicaOutput2012519111731.900549.rtf`

Then you would say `Export[out, ...]`.

If you want to have the date in a more readable and less detailed form, you could use this for the name:

```
"file-" <> Riffle[ToString /@ Date[][[;;3]], "-"] <> ".pdf"
```

> `file-2012-5-19.pdf`

And of course, the content of any other variable could be inserted in the file name using `ToString` if needed. If you need a different separator between the data components, the `Riffle` command can be modified accordingly, by changing the second argument to another string that is allowed in filenames on your platform.

The `FileNameJoin` command is only needed if you'd like to create not just file names but directory structures in a cross-platform fashion.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a variation on Jens' answer:

```
"file-" <> DateString[Riffle[{"Year", "Month", "Day"}, "-"]] <> ".pdf"

(*
==> "file-2012-05-19.pdf"
*)
```

which has the advantage of automatically padding the month and day with zeros so that the file names will sort nicely.

Comment: nice and clean!  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is shorter without `Riffle`: `"file-" <> DateString[{"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}] <> ".pdf"
`