# Construct file names using a number and a string prefix

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to append filenames with *Mathematica*, and cannot do it.
The output of my calculation are two lists : `X` and `Y`, calculated for a varying parameter `G`.

So I want to have `X0, Y0` for `G = 0`, `X0.5, Y0.5` for `G = 0.5`, etc. In python, I would just automate this by defining `X"$G"`, `Y"$G"`, and do a loop on `G`.

Is there an equivalent in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Take a look at StringJoin and ToString.

Comment: Also see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5795/245).

Comment: The title talks about file names, but the question itself never mentions any I/O operation. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but you can deal with strings quite nicely in Mathematica. For instance, say you have x="this" and y="that" and you want to write ten files that are numbered consectutively. You might create

```
 fileNames=Table[StringJoin[x, y, ToString[i]], {i, 1, 10}]
```

which gives you a list of 10 file names. Of course you can build the names up any way you wish.