# Save all the variable with file name containing the Time stamp

Tags: files-and-directories, file-transfer, dumpsave

How to save all the variable with a filename containing the Timestamp. For example:
If the current time is `2:30:56 PM`, The file name should be `FileName_143056`.

I am currently using

```
Names["Global`*"] (*Check they're there*)
DumpSave["G:\\Mathematica\\dump.mx", "Global`"];
```

This worked out

```
out = FileNameJoin@{$UserDocumentsDirectory, 
   "MathematicaOutput" <> ToString /@ Date[] <> ".mx"}
DumpSave[out, "Global`"]
```

[Source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/how-to-dynamically-name-and-date-a-file-for-export)

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is quite straightoforward with `DateString` and `StringJoin`.

Comment: I google it, Didn't get anything related to it. Will try now using those!

Comment: I tried this: StringJoin[ToString[TimeObject[][[1]][[1]]], 
 ToString[TimeObject[][[1]][[2]]], ToString[(TimeObject[][[1]][[3]])]]

Comment: Why didn;t you use DateString or the linked topic approach? I'm sorry I am confused, what is the line below 'I tried this'. And why do you say it worked out if the result does not match your request?

Comment: I removed the 'I tried this part'. I tried this, it almost worked. But finally found the answer at the link provided in the source.