# Copying Greek text from notebooks as unicode

Tags: front-end, unicode, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “Copy as Unicode” from a Notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook)

How can I copy Greek text from notebooks as proper Unicode that can be pasted into other applications?  If I type some Greek text into a notebook, and then try to paste it elsewhere, it ends up as a set of character names in Mathematica's notation.  The screenshot below illustrated the problem.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It doesn't really matter if the Greek text is typed elsewhere, then pasted into Mathematica, or if it's typed directly into Mathematica: when copying *from* Mathematica, Greek letters are converted into character names.

If you don't have a Greek keyboard layout installed, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVrc.png) can be useful for testing.

**Use case:** analysing Greek text and copying results from a notebook.

Comment: I second @R.M.'s comment that it's an exact duplicate. But if we ever get a set of methods that works fo all platforms, it would be great to include that in the StackExchange Copy palette so that code with things like `\[Element]` becomes easier to read.

Comment: @R.M I edited the title.  Now it's not a duplicate any more as it only refers to Greek.

Comment: I don't think that changing the title makes this less of a duplicate. It's now just a special case.

Comment: @Jens It's not a duplicate because the answer I gave only applies to Greek text (my current use case) and not to other characters, such as `\[LongRightArrow]`.  This answer will work for as long as the only concern is handling Greek text.  But if the questions get merged, I don't mind.

Comment: I just saw your answer - didn't think there would be such a specialized case, but I guess with that point of view one can leave this open as a separate issue.

Comment: @Jens I would have answered on the other thread, but the workaround is for Windows only, and has some potentially undesirable side effect.  I wouldn't recommend it for those who only want to copy Greek *variable names*.  However, for Greek text processing it's a useful workaround.

Comment: I use vim to insta-replace all my `\[Greek]` but if you're using notepad, I have no help.

Comment: Looking at this again, I still cannot understand why you would not simply use Mr. Wizard's copy function from the [related answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1148/245). It seems so much more powerful!?

Comment: I feel a bit odd closing one of your questions in "favor" of my own, but I think this is a legitimate duplicate.  I hope you agree; if not, please make the case to reopen.

Comment: Hope [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45046/17) can help.

Answer (score 4):

The following workaround works at least for Linux with Mathematica version 8.0.0.0; it might work on other systems, too:

**Step 1:** Open a terminal window (with UTF8 encoding) and start directly the kernel there.

**Step 2:** Enter `$CharacterEncoding="UTF8"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Ideally the kernel would figure that out itself from the locale, but for some reason it doesn't. *Note:* If you make a mistake here (e.g. forgetting the quotes, or mistyping the encoding) and get an error message about a non-supported encoding, *quit the kernel in the terminal and start a new one*. At least for 8.0.0.0, after an error, further assignments of that variable don't affect the output any more (I have no idea why).

**Step 3:** Copy/paste your output from the notebook to the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. While the input is still in Mathematica `\[...]` form, the output will be in Unicode (be aware however that Mathematica uses private-use characters for some special characters like `\[Equal]`; those will not appear correctly — however that this is only relevant for characters in strings; `Equal` expressions will show up with `==`. If all you need are Greek characters, you won't have any problems.)

**Step 4:** Copy/paste the output of step 3 to where you want it.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following workaround for Windows systems.  Go to the Control Panel and select Regional & Language Options.  Under the Advanced tab select "Greek" as the language for non-Unicode programs.  Note that the option to change is *not* the language for "Standards and Formats".  It is the language for non-Unicode programs.

Now Greek letters will be copied as Unicode from notebooks.

**Warning:** This *might* break the display of some characters in non-Unicode programs, and I won't be surprised if it has other side effects as well (e.g. non-Unicode programs may not be able to read from directories with certain accented characters in the name).  Use with caution!

Comment: With that many side-effects, I'm not sure if it'll be helpful...

Comment: @R.M It depends.  This is the default on Greek versions of Windows and is probably useful as a default for Greek speakers who might name their directories in Greek.  If you're going to do some text processing on Greek texts, then I think it's a useful workaround.  If you want to copy variable names, then I wouldn't recommend it.  (This is why I didn't simply post this answer on the other thread.)

Comment: Ah, Greek version of Windows. Hmmm.