# Greek letters don't depending of the font

Tags: fonts

For some reason mathematica (11.0.1 Windows 10 64-bit) does no use greek letter font from the selected font by

```
FontFamily -> "AnyFont"
```

When I check the lambda character for any font with :

```
 Take[$FontFamilies, All];
 Style[\[Lambda], FontFamily -> #, 30] & /@ %
```

I get only 3 kinds of lambda. They does not seems to belong to special type of fonts (like "Serif", "Sans" etc.).

Where does this come from ?

(I check this : [Wrong font selection for some characters in Mathematica 10 for Linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55711/wrong-font-selection-for-some-characters-in-mathematica-10-for-linux) 
I suppress greek letter replacement but it does not change anything)

Thank you !

edit :

```
L = Rasterize[Style[\[Lambda], FontFamily -> #, 30]] & /@ $FontFamilies
```

givs this (just a part of the whole result) :

[image: lambda]

One can clearly see there is only 3 type of lambda (with variations with repect to the property of the font used I guess).

and :

```
 {Length[L], Length[DeleteDuplicates[L]]}
```

gives :

```
{343,174}
```

Comment: Not all fonts include glyphs for everything in Unicode (in fact, most don't).  Can you create a lambda in all of these fonts in other pieces of software in your system?

Comment: On "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" I get 336 *different* lambdas for 442 available font families. `L = Rasterize[Style[\[Lambda], FontFamily -> #, 30]] & /@ $FontFamilies` and then `{Length[L], Length[DeleteDuplicates[L]]}` gives `{442, 336}`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert : yep For exemple for Latin Modern Math or Computer Modern fonts I get the right "lambda" on LibreOffice/Words etc. but not on Mathematica.


@Roman : It gives `{343,174}` but this is is only 3 type of lambda with lot of variation (size and  offset from the baseline with respect to the standard size/position of the different fonts) I will add screenshot in my original post, it will be more clear.

Comment: After looking a bit more closely, I confirm that on "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" there are also only three different lambdas. The rest of the variation comes from size and shift variations.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that this is due to their status as [special characters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html).  Since they aren't part of the standard character set, they probably don't get transformed in the standard way under a font change.

Comment: Yep but it does not me a lot ^^

I found on Mathrmatica documentation : "Following common convention, lowercase Greek letters are rendered slightly slanted in the standard fonts provided with the Wolfram System, while capital Greek letters are unslanted. On Greek systems, however, the Wolfram System will render all Greek letters unslanted so that standard Greek fonts can be used."

Something  should be done !