# What is the font that is most similar to latex fonts?

Tags: fonts

I am producing mathematica graphs so I hope the axis font can be as similar to latex fonts as possible. This is because I need to put them in a latex document.

[$\LaTeX$ and Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/736/latex-and-mathematica)

What is stated in the above link is quite difficult and I do not have enough time. What is the font family (available for selection in mathematica), other than Computer Modern, that is most similar to latex fonts?
Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: You know you can select the LaTeX font to match the ones available in Mathematica? For example, Times, Helvetica, Courier...

Comment: @Marius Ladegård Meyer Mac Mavericks

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84968/using-greek-latex-fonts,

Comment: You can get facsimile cmr fonts in ttf format: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/ttf/

Comment: I've added an answer to the Q&A linked by @yohbs because I think it could be considered a duplicate. So please look at [my suggestion here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87756/245).

Comment: @Jens Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @yohbs Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Yves Klett  I will try this.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76943/12) in the question you linked.  It has a link to fonts.