# Export Latin Modern Math Greek: spurious spacing on Windows

Tags: bugs, export, latex, fonts, unicode

**Bug introduced in 12.0.0 or earlier on Windows**

[CASE:4549185]

---

To get simple LaTeX Greek in my figures, I am using `U+1D6FC MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL ALPHA` to `U+1D714 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL OMEGA` in the font "Latin Modern Math" (see ["Symbols defined by unicode-math"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)).

But the output is different on the two machines I am using:

- 12.0.1 for Linux ARM (32-bit)
- 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

```
styledGreek = Framed @ Column @ {
  $Version,
  Style[
    CharacterRange[16^^1D6FC, 16^^1D714],
    FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math",
    FontSize -> 24
  ]
}

Export[ToLowerCase[$SystemID] <> ".png", styledGreek]
Export[ToLowerCase[$SystemID] <> ".pdf", styledGreek]
```

### Linux PNG (OK)

[image: Linux PNG export (OK)]

### Linux PDF (OK)

[image: Linux PDF export (OK)]

### Windows PNG (spurious vertical spacing)

[image: Windows PNG export (spurious vertical spacing)]

### Windows PDF (spurious vertical *and* horizontal spacing)

[image: Windows PDF export (spurious vertical and horizontal spacing)]

**What is going on here?**

I have checked the OTFs installed on the two machines (`latinmodern-math.otf` from [GUST](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html)) and they are identical (SHA256: 6075562b771f8b82f0c179e363389684f2dd09de30038269e2628e504bd7be0f).

---

NOTES:

- I already know about MaTeX.
- Related: [Szabolcs on Greek](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84971).