# FontFamily option in Style being ignored

Tags: front-end, fonts

`Style[\[WhiteKnight], FontFamily -> "Segoe UI Symbol"]`

The output I'm getting looks like it is in the Mathematica.ttf font, not the designated Segoe UI Symbol font. How can I get the character displayed in the font I have chosen?

Comment: I guess it's just a crazy symbol which does not exist in other fonts

Comment: when an unicode character like \[WhiteKnight] both exists in the Mathematica font and Segoe UI Symbol font, Mathematica use its own to render. How can I force it to use the Segoe UI Symbol font?

Comment: Are you on Win10? See [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Segoe+UI+Symbol&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=vngLVuqPC8L5aujVregL), and note only if the Font is installed the font will be rendered correctly, See also [Export to PDF on OS X, font missing on Windows](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45947/export-to-pdf-on-os-x-font-missing-on-windows/57936#57936)

Comment: Win 7 here. I don't know whats up but that font doesn't work properly even manually applying font format in a text cell ( Yes its installed and displays fine in office . Unicode 9816 is a glyph of a train in `Segoe UI Symbol` in Word )

Comment: `MemberQ[$FontFamilies, "Segoe UI Symbol"]` -> `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Mathematica forces to display some usual characters into Mathematica font only. This is the case of your `\[WhiteKnight]`:

```
Style[\[WhiteKnight], FontFamily -> "Apple Symbols", FontSize -> 40]
```

[image]

I clearly have a different `\[WhiteKnight]` symbol available in my "Apple Symbols" system font but it is not displayed here above.

Actually I found some nice **solutions** in these posts: **[wrong-font-selection-for-some-characters-in-mathematica-10-for-linux](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55711/wrong-font-selection-for-some-characters-in-mathematica-10-for-linux)** and **[how-to-write-plain-greek-in-a-text-cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32684/how-to-write-plain-greek-in-a-text-cell)**

As I have Mathematica version >= 10.0, i followed **@DBM / @AlexeyBobrick** well explained instructions and I am now able to get the "correct" display:

[image]

To do the same you'll have to know the character code of your symbol, which is given by:

```
ToCharacterCode @ ToString @ \[WhiteKnight]
```

> {9816}

#### Automated "fix" for v>=10

In case, you have version >=10.0 and don't want to fix the problem manually, I wrote **an automated version**:

**1.** Check first if the system file "FontMap.tr" exists:

```
fontmapfile = FileNames["FontMap.tr", $InstallationDirectory, Infinity] // First
```

> ```
> /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/\
> TextResources/FontMap.tr
> ```

If the command fails and does not return a file path as above, STOP here (there might be some different approach for your system).

**2.** If the file exists, you can modify it automatically this way (it should be safe, as you can see i backup the original file and don't modify it)

```
backupfile = fontmapfile <> ".BKUP";
backupfile // If[Not@FileExistsQ[#], CopyFile[fontmapfile, #]] &;
ToExpression@Import[backupfile] /. {9816 -> Sequence[]} // Compress // 
  Export[fontmapfile, "CompressedData[\"" <> ToString@# <> "\"]", 
    "String"] &;
```

***(If you want to include other symbols, you'll just have to add their code to the list `{9816 -> Nothing}`)***

**3.** That's it. Quit and Restart mathematica and you should now be able to display your symbol(s).