# How do I use Greek characters in the WindowTitle option of CreateWindow?

Tags: windows, character-encoding

I am trying to write some exercises in Greek using `CreateWindow`. My problem is with using Greek characters in the option `WindowTitle`. For example, with

```
CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook[{a}, WindowTitle -> "Ενα"]]
```

I get a new window with the title, `Ε\[Nu]\[Alpha]`, and no one can understand this title. How cam I get the proper glyphs instead of their full names?

Comment: What OS are you using?  On Windows the solution to this is to make sure that the system locale is set to Greek. [See here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6274/12).

Comment: No problems for me on OS X

Comment: @Szabolcs I am using Windows 7 and the system locale is set to Greek. I think that  this is a problem of Mathematica. ! I have no problem with "Copying Greek text from notebooks as unicode" The problem is with  the Window Title! If you have Windows  installed, please try no Latin letters like  Chinese! Thanks

Comment: @kornaros I don't have Windows any more unfortunately, otherwise I would have tried it out ...