# How do I obtain the correct double limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

The command

```
Limit[(Sin[x^2] + Sin[y^2])/ (x - y) /. x -> 0, y -> 0]
(*
   0
*)
```

I think that *Mathematica* finds the iterated limit instead of the double limit. It should be noted that [WolframAlpha produces the correct answer, when asking for](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28sin%28x%5E2%29%2bsin%28y%5E2%29%29/%28x-y%29%20as%20x-%3E0%20and%20y-%3E0&dataset=)

> "limit (sin(x^2)+sin(y^2))/(x-y) as x->0 and y->0"

[image]

Comment: By the way, Mathematica's natural language interpretation translates "limit (sin(x^2)+sin(y^2))/(x-y) as x->0 and y->0", to `Limit[(Sin[x^2] + Sin[y^2])/(x - y), {x -> 0, y -> 0}]`, which of course is something different because `Limit` is `Listable`. Just saying

Comment: @Rojo: the output of Limit[(Sin[x^2] + Sin[y^2])/(x - y), {x -> 0, y -> 0}] is {-(Sin[y^2]/y), Sin[x^2]/x}

Comment: I think WolframAlpha must use heuristics sometimes to guess the answer.  This one it gets wrong: "limit (x y^2/(x^2-y^4)) as x->0 and y->0" -- says it's zero, but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let

```
f = (Sin[x^2] + Sin[y^2])/(x - y)
```

be the function in question.

As pointed out in the answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21544/finding-limits-in-several-variables), finding multivariable limits automatically computationally is full of pitfalls.  The idea behind the function `lim` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21544/finding-limits-in-several-variables/21562#21562) was to use `Maximum` and `Minimum` to find bounds on the function and apply the squeeze theorem.  It fails here because `Maximum` and `Minimum` fail on `f`.  However the concept is sound.  The first two methods below apply this concept.  A third method of testing for nonexistence is included at the end.

## Numerical approximation

A nonrigorous way to go is to get numerical evidence.

```
NMaximize[{f, -0.01 < x < 0.01 && -0.01 < y < 0.01}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>
>
> {1.53512*10^13, {x -> 0.00893814, y -> 0.00893814}}
> ```

```
NMinimize[f, -0.01 < x < 0.01 && -0.01 < y < 0.01}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> NMinimize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>
>
> {-2.44609*10^11, {x -> -0.0085679, y -> -0.0085679}}
> ```

It appears the function diverges.  How close to `{0, 0}` to restrict `{x, y}` would have to be decided in each particular case.

One can automatically check smaller and smaller neighborhoods:

```
limitExistQ[f_, vars_, point_, epsilon_: 0.001, delta0_: 0.1] :=
 Module[{notExists},
  NestWhile[#/10 &, 
   delta0,
   (notExists = 
     First @ NMaximize[{f, And @@ MapThread[Less, {point - #, vars, point + #}]}, vars] -
     First @ NMinimize[{f, And @@ MapThread[Less, {point - #, vars, point + #}]}, vars] >= epsilon) &,
   1, 5];
  ! notExists]
```

Example:

```
limitExistQ[f, {x, y}, {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>
> NMinimize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. >>
> ,,,
>
> False
> ```

It is still only approximate, as can be seen from varying `epsilon` and `delta0` in the following limit, which exists:

```
limitExistQ[(x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y}, {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
limitExistQ[(x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y}, {0, 0}, 10^-6]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
limitExistQ[(x^3 + y^3)/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y}, {0, 0}, 10^-6, 0.001]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

## A sometimes rigorous method

Sometimes, the method in the [referenced answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21544/finding-limits-in-several-variables/21562#21562) can be adapted by substituting Taylor polynomial approximations to the numerator or denominator of the function, since rational functions are easier to deal with than transcendental or algebraic functions.  For it to be rigorous, you have to know (be able to prove) that the limit of the approximation is the same as the limit of the function.

For instance, one might know how to bound the error of the Taylor approximation and deduce that the error is negligible.  In the case of the function in the question, there is in the numerator `Sin[x^2]`, whose Taylor series at `x == 0` is alternating and absolutely decreasing for `Abs[x] < 1`.  It follows that the numerator of `f` is bounded successive Taylor polynomials (for example, of degrees 2 and 6 in this case).

Below is code for handling such cases. The first functions replace the numerator and/or the denominator with a Taylor polynomial approximation, unless it is already a polynomial or the degree specified is `Infinity`. 
The variable `deg` in `getApproximations` is a list of two degrees: the degree to be used for approximating the function to be maximized, typically a lower bound, and the degree to be used for approximating the function to be minimized, typically an upper bound.  (If one wants different degrees for the numerators and denominators, adapt as desired.)

```
  (* does not expand polynomials -- change if desired *)
makeApproximation[f0_, deg0_, vars_, centers_] := 
  If[deg0 === Infinity || PolynomialQ[f0, vars], f0, 
   Normal@Series[f0, 
     Sequence @@ MapThread[{#1, #2, deg0} &, {vars, centers}]]
   ];
getApproximations[f_, deg_List, vars_, centers_] := 
  Module[{num, den, minNum, maxNum, minDen, maxDen},
   {num, den} = {Numerator[#], Denominator[#]} &@Together[f];
   {minNum, maxNum} = makeApproximation[num, #, vars, centers] & /@ deg;
   {minDen, maxDen} = makeApproximation[den, #, vars, centers] & /@ deg,
   {minNum, maxNum, minDen, maxDen}
   ];
```

The modification to use polynomial approximations is as follows.
The `Print` statements are included to reveal a little of what's going on and may be omitted.

```
serlim[f0_, deg_, vars_List -> point_List] := 
 Module[{lim0, d, max, min, minNum, maxNum, minDen, maxDen},
  {minNum, maxNum, minDen, maxDen} = getApproximations[f0, deg, vars, point];
  max = Maximize[{maxNum/maxDen, 
     0 < d < 1 && And @@ MapThread[-d <= #1 - #2 <= d &, {vars, point}]},
     vars, Reals];
  If[Head[max] === Maximize,(*Maximize failed to find a max*)
   Return[$Failed], max = Simplify[First @ max, d > 0];
   Print[Row @ {"Max ", max}];
   min = Minimize[{minNum/minDen, 
      0 < d < 1 && And @@ MapThread[-d <= #1 - #2 <= d &, {vars, point}]},
      vars, Reals];
   If[Head[min] === Minimize,(*Minimize failed to find a min*)
    Return[$Failed], min = Simplify[First @ min, d > 0]]];
  Print[Row @ {"Min ", min}];
  lim0 = Limit[max, d -> 0];
  If[lim0 == Limit[min, d -> 0], lim0, "Does not exist."]]
```

Here is the result of applying it to `f`

```
serlim[f, {2, 6}, {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> Max \[Piecewise]   \[Infinity]    d$1011674 < 1
>                   -\[Infinity]    True
>
> Min \[Piecewise]  -\[Infinity]    d$1011674 < 1
>                    \[Infinity]    True
>
> "Does not exist."
> ```

The approximations being used are constructed from

```
getApproximations[f, {2, 6}, {x, y}, {0, 0}]
```

> ```
> {x^2 + y^2, x^2 - x^6/6 + y^2 - y^6/6, x - y ,  x - y}
> (* minNum ,       maxNum             , minDen, maxDen *)
> ```

Thus `serlim` is maximizing the lower bound `(x^2 - x^6/6 + y^2 - y^6/6) / (x - y)` and  minimizing the upper bound `(x^2 + y^2) / (x - y)`.
Since they do not converge to the same finite number,
the limit does not exist.

*Edit: Remark on the present case.*  In fact, for $-1 < x,y < 1$, $x \ne y$, we can easily deduce that our function lies between $(x^2+y^2)/[3\,(x-y)]$ and $(x^2+y^2)/(x-y)$.  If $(x^2+y^2)/(x-y)$ goes to infinity then both bounds go to infinity and `f` with them.  Hence this somewhat faster calculation may be used to determine the limit does not exist:

```
serlim[f, {2, 2}, {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
```

## A less robust approach

This will work sometimes.  We find the curve along which the denominator is zero, and approach along various paths approaching the curve.  It is reliable if it finds the limit does not exist, but otherwise it is unreliable.

```
rule = Reduce[1/f == 0, {x, y}] // ToRules // First
```

> ```
> y -> x
> ```

```
If[Equal @@ #, First[#], "Does not exist."] &@
 With[{sub = First[rule] -> Last[rule] + delta},
  Table[
   Limit[f /. sub /. {x -> t, y -> t}, t -> 0],
   {delta, {t, t^2, t^5, t^10, E^(-1/t^2)}}]]
```

> ```
> "Does not exist."
> ```

`Solve` might be used in place of `Reduce`.  Sometimes there may be many solutions corresponding to many curves where the denominator is zero; the code above would have to be adapted to handle such cases.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Mathematica gives you the correct answer to your input. You first specify that x should be replaced by 0 and afterwards the limit of y->0 should be calculated. The correct answer to that is 0. And yes, this is exactly the same as taking the limit x->0 first and taking the limit y->0 afterwards.
If the double limit exists it is the same as taking the limits in any order. Unfortunately there seems to be no method integrated into mathematica to check for the existence of the limit with respect to a certain norm.

Comment: Hey look everybody, another Wizard. :-)

Comment: Yeah, always loved wizards. It's my pleasure to meat another one :).

Comment: Whoa, slow down, I don't want to get *that* friendly! =:O ("meat" lol)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you'll have to go back to Spartacus

Answer (score 3):

If you enter it this way

```
Limit[(Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2)/(x - y), {x -> y}]
(* Output: {DirectedInfinity[…]} *)
```

or alternatively you can try

```
Limit[(Sin[x]^2 + Sin[y]^2)/(x - y) /. x -> y, y -> 0]
(* Output: ComplexInfinity *)
```

In your input, you have used [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll&lang=en), `/.`, to first Replace all x's with zero, after which you find the limit as y -> 0. This may not be what you intend.

Note that if you wish you can use the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html?q=Assumptions&lang=en) option as the third argument to [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Limit.html?q=Limit&lang=en) to restrict your variables to [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reals.html?q=Reals&lang=en), for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, these are not the same as the double limit under consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Start from *v11.2*, `Limit` is able to calculate multivariate limit, and it correctly finds the limit doesn't exist:

```
Limit[(Sin[x^2] + Sin[y^2])/(x - y), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe another way to look at it is to change variables :

```
subs = {x -> Sqrt[a + b], y -> Sqrt[a - b]};
expr = FullSimplify[(Sin[x^2] + Sin[y^2])/(x - y) /. subs]
(* -((2 Cos[b] Sin[a])/(Sqrt[a - b] - Sqrt[a + b])) *)
```

This should make the path dependence of the limit a bit more explicit :

```
Limit[expr, a -> b]
(* (Sqrt[2] Cos[b] Sin[b])/Sqrt[b] *)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the relation a->b does not imply x->0, only y->0. This is not it at all.

Comment: Of course, but you can take the limit `b->0` if you want to.

Comment: Limit[Sqrt[2]* Cos[b] *Sin[b]/Sqrt[b], b -> 0] produces 0.