# Plot a function over a specific domain

Tags: plotting

I have a function that is defined on a specific domain for example the function $$f(x,y)=(x-0.5)*(y-0.5)$$ defined on $\Sigma$ which is the circle $(x-0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2=0.5^2$

How to plot $f$ over $\Sigma$?

I tried something like

```
Plot3D[(-0.5 + x) (-0.5 + y), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
RegionFunction -> 
Function[{x, y}, 0.5^2 - 0.01 <= (x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 <= 0.5^2 + 0.01]]
```

but I am looking for something better.

Comment: Have you considered reparametrizing in polar coordinates, and then using `ParametricPlot3D[]`?

Comment: If you use options like `PlotPoints -> 100` the results is quite nice I think.

Comment: "Better" in what sense, precisely?

Comment: Yeah, precisely. Whats wrong with RegionFunction?

Comment: @whuber Well, what I tried gave a plot with discontinuities. `PlotPoints->100` seems to solve this. However it essentially gives a band around the solution, defined a parameter (in this case 0.01). Changing the parameter leads again to problems. So I am looking for a more natural way to solve this.

Comment: The best solution is by @J.M. : `ParametricPlot3D[{1/2 Cos[t], 
  1/2 Sin[t], (-1/2 + 1/2 Cos[t]) (-1/2 + 1/2 Sin[t])}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: I think it's very similar to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20565/17).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Plot3D[
 (x - .5) (y - .5),                        (*  your f(x,y)       *)
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z},
   (x - .5)^2 + (y - .5)^2 - .5^2          (*  your Σ equation   *)
   ],
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Red,
 PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution and it has the advantage that it works even when parametrization is difficult.

Comment: @Jim Thanks. In fact implicit functions are sometimes easier to use than parametric ones. Please compare to [this similar question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20565/17).