# plot a specific path on a surface

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a 3D function (z = f(x, y)). I have plot it correctly as you can see below. Now, I want to show that there are two different paths to reach from Point A to Point B as shown in the following image.

[image]

As you can see, I have done it using Shockwell in Linux. But, I want to do it in a clean manner in Mathematica. How can I plot a path from Point A to B while the path is on the surface?

And, if it is possible, as you can see, my preference is to draw an arrow. But, it is not totally necessary.

Comment: What are the definitions of `f` and the `specific` paths?

Comment: See [Plot a 2D vector path onto a surface](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/plot-a-2d-vector-path-onto-a-surface)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Draw your plot with `Plot3D` and your paths with `ParametricPlot3D`, then combine them with `Show`

```
zfunc[x_, y_] := Exp[x y];
path1[x_] := x^2
path2[x_] := Sqrt[x]

Show[
 Plot3D[zfunc[x, y], {x, 0, 1.1}, {y, 0, 1.1}],
 (ParametricPlot3D[{
     {x, path1[x], zfunc[x, path1[x]]},
     {x, path2[x], zfunc[x, path2[x]]}},
    {x, 0, 1},
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Red, Arrowheads[.02]}], 
      Directive[{Blue, Arrowheads[.02]}]}] /. Line -> Arrow)
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason. Sorry for late response. I was wondering for two things. 1- sometimes the arrow hides behind the surface. How can I _bring_ _it_ _forward_? 2- Since I am a little bit stupid on Mathematica, how can I increase arrow's width? Make it **bolder** as we speak.

Comment: To make the path always on top of the surface, you could manually put in an offset in the z-coordinate of the paths:  `ParametricPlot3D[{{x, path1[x], zfunc[x, path1[x]] + .01}, {x, 
   path2[x], zfunc[x, path2[x]] + .01}}` for example offsets the plot by 0.01 in the z-direction.

Comment: To bolden the lines, you could change `Line-> Arrow` to `Line[pts_] :> Arrow[Tube[pts, .0075], {0, -.1}]`

Comment: Thanks Jason. Appreciate it. I was hoping that there might be a way to show the arrows like **threads**. This way that you are mentioning would shift the arrow up which in some cases will detach the arrow from the surface. Also, for the top gray section, it will have no effect :)