# 2D function on a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to put an ellipse given by:

```
ParametricPlot[{2.5 + 1.5 Cos[Pi/3 t], 2.4 + 1.1 Sin[Pi/3 t]}, {t, 0, 6}]
```

onto a 3D plot of a large function composed of several different parts, which essentially displays a mountain range. How do I get the 2D ellipse to show up on the 3D plot?
For reference, my 3D plot is given by:

```
Plot3D[m[x, y], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

I won't put m[x,y] here because it will take up very much space, but it is essentially 4-5 peaks over the given interval.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20565)?

Comment: I've gone through what you linked and tried a couple of things, but I couldn't quite figure out how to correctly adjust my function for the mountain range m(x,y) since I already have values of epsilon, lambda, and r.