# Display a 3-dimensional surface with a 3-dimensional line on it

Tags: plotting, graphics

I can display a 3D surface with z-axis {z,-100, 15000}: Plot3D[n2U[v, n], {v, -100.0, 20.0}, {n, 0.0, 1.0}].

I can plot a 3D line: ListLinePlot3D[mydata] which has z-axis {z, -100, 12000}. The line happens to lie on the 3D surface but that is not relevant to the question:

How can I display the 3D surface and the 3D line in the same 3D cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: Can you, please, provide some minimal working code for the `Plot3D` and the `ListLinePlot3D`?

Comment: What does ***Heading*** have to do with anything??

Comment: Across the top of the screen you should see "Search on Mathematica..." I typed "draw line on plot" in that box, but did not include those quotes, and found several likely answers in the first ten results. From that I used one of those answers `Show[Plot3D[x+y,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},PlotStyle-> Green], Graphics3D[{Red,Line[{{-1,-1,-2},{1,1,2}}]}]]` Adjust that as needed.

Comment: Similar to [20565](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20565/plot-a-2d-vector-path-onto-a-surface).

Comment: Thank you, Bill. This "Show"s me how to proceed (pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

You may use "Show" for this:

```
line = ListLinePlot3D[Table[{x, 0, x^2}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.01]}];
Show[{line,
  Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
  }]
```

[image]