# Converting Mathematica Greek letters from Notebook to Unicode Form in SE

Tags: front-end

Related :

> [How to "Copy as Unicode" from a Notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook/1148#1148)

```
Plot[\[Alpha], {\[Alpha], 0, 8}]

cellExpression

(*
Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{Plot,[,RowBox[{\[Alpha],,,RowBox[{{,RowBox[{\[Alpha],,,0,,,8}],}}]}],
]}]],Input,CellChangeTimes->{3.58068*10^9,{3.58068*10^9,3.58068*10^9}}]
*)

CellExpression2InputText[cellExpression_] := First[FrontEndExecute[
FrontEnd`ExportPacket[cellExpression, "InputText"]]]

CellExpression2InputText[cellExpression]

(*
Plot[\[Alpha], {\[Alpha], 0, 8}]
*)

CellExpression2InputText[cellExpression] // CopyToClipboard

Paste[]

Plot[\[Alpha], {\[Alpha], 0, 8}]
```

when copy the result above to SE, the [Alpha] was not shown in Unicode Form. And I failed in my usage involved with `CellExpression2InputText`

Mr.Wizard's method, this is good to copy directly from input cell.

```
SetAttributes[copyUnicode, HoldFirst]
copyUnicode[expr_, form_: InputForm] :=
Run["clip <", Export["$Clipboard.temp", ToString[Unevaluated @ expr, form],
"Text", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]];
```

#### case 1

```
CellExpression2InputText[cellExpression] // copyUnicode

Paste[]
```

PasteResult（not good）

```
CellExpression2InputText[cellExpression]
```

#### case 2

```
ToExpression[CellExpression2InputText[cellExpression], InputForm, HoldForm] // copyUnicode

Paste[]
```

still not good

### question

---

So question is clear:

How to convert `CellExpression` to string/clipboard with greek letters in Unicode Form when copy to SE without laborious work by hand.

```
\[Alpha] ==> to α
```

Comment: I thought you understood after the discussion in meta that you shouldn't use combine quote form and comment form to format an output cell in markdown. Evidently, I was wrong, so I tell you now: don't do it.

Comment: @m_goldberg aha, fine, ok, I will modify my package to generate that differ from the old styles.

Comment: @m_goldberg help, When I'm reading the MarkDown help page, I have trouble comprehending this sentence.`Like code blocks, code spans will be displayed in a monospaced font. Markdown and HTML will not work within them. Note that, [unlike] code blocks, code spans require you to manually escape any HTML within!` I donot know what is the unlike mean. Because I found that they both keep the html tags.

Comment: I don't think this comment thread is the place to discuss this. Post it as a question in meta, or take it up in chat.

Comment: @m_goldberg ok, seems a little tiny as a question in meta. I haven't used chat by far, maybe I should try that.

Comment: It's not too small a question for meta in my opinion.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45046/17) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this specific case there is a solution which does not rely on *Mathematica*. Since the greek characters copied from *Mathematica* were a general problem here on our site which made code-blocks tedious to read, I have adapted a stolen user script. This can be installed as extension into browsers and provides additional buttons which let you (beside other things) make this conversion easily.

Please read [this meta post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/187) for more information and a installation guide.

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm not on Windows and you apparently are, I would guess that you can fix this problem by wrapping your `cellExpression` as follows:

```
ToExpression[cellExpression, InputForm, HoldForm]
```

The output of your function `CellExpression2InputText` escapes the backslashes defining *Mathematica*'s special characters, so they aren't translated to Unicode. But this added escape level is removed in `ToExpression`.