# Changing "Block[]" to a Manipulation

Tags: manipulate

I have a graph here and I want to be able to manipulate the 4 parameters that are in the Block command. I want to watch the graph change as I change the parameters.

I've done this before, but the Block command that Mathematica suggested throws me off a little bit.

Here is the code:

```
 test = Block[{ε = 3, ω0 = 1, ωf = 1.788, 
 A = 5}, Reap[
 NDSolve[{x''[t] == ε (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - ω0^2*x[t] + 
     A*Sin[ωf*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 π/ωf] == 0, 
    Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 10000}, 
  MaxSteps -> ∞]]][[-1, 1]];

ListPlot[test, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0035]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Memoize NDSolve**

If you want to convince with a Manipulation it must be smooth. But I'm sorry to say, that if you naively choose all the parameters and use them for `Manipulate` this is frustrating slow.

The thing I'm trying here is to memoize the output of `NDSolve` inside a `DynamicModule`, which lives inside a `Manipulate`.

This is the first time I've done this and it is actually working pretty well (with lots of help of Mma I guess...).

```
Manipulate[
    DynamicModule[{},
        ListPlot[lpFunc[eps, om0, omf, A][[-1, 1]], ImageSize -> Medium, 
                 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0035]],
        Initialization :> (lpFunc[eps_, om0_, omf_, a_] := 
           lpFunc[eps, om0, omf, a] = 
              Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] == 
                eps (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - om0^2*x[t] + A*Sin[omf*t], 
                x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
                WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 π/omf] == 0, 
                Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 10000}, 
                MaxSteps -> ∞]]])
   ],
   {{eps, 3, ε}, 1, 5},
   {{om0, 1, ω0}, 1, 5},
   {{omf, 1.788, ωf}, 0, 5},
   {{A, 5}, 1, 10},
   TrackedSymbols -> {eps}
]
```

Your differential equation has very easily some singularities, so you better limit the range of what a user may choose, but this is your choice. I've chosen *eps* as the trigger to re-evaluate the plot (if it isn't already memoized).

**Update: Gain some speed!**

Although I think that the solution so far is nice, it is still not a decent Manipulate experience. So not a good advertisement.

What I'd do if I were you is the following:

1) Rewrite the function for `NDSolve`: (please have a look first at the bottom of this post, where @rcollyer rewrote the function inside a `Compile` block, gaining a massive speed improvement.)

```
lpFunc[eps_, om0_, omf_, A_] := 
lpFunc[eps, om0, omf, A] = 
    Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] == eps (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - om0^2*x[t] + A*Sin[omf*t], x[0] == 1, 
        x'[0] == 0, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 Pi/omf] == 0, Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 10000},
        MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
        Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}
    ]
]
```

I wanted to make NDSolve faster, that's why I turned off *SymbolicProcessing*, since this will be evaluated by the optimizer hundred of times.

2) Generate a table of precalculated results:

```
ParallelTable[Quiet@lpFunc[eps, om0, omf, a], {eps, 1, 5, 0.2}, {om0, 1, 5, 0.2}, 
    {omf, 0, 5, 0.2}, {a, 1, 10, 0.2}];
```

Now it's time to go out for lunch break or anything else, but it must take time...

3) DumpSave the symbol *lpFunc* to a .mx file:

```
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
DumpSave["preprocessed.mx", lpFunc];
```

4) Create a new notebook and import the .mx file and define your Manipulate:

```
SetDirectory[$TemporaryDirectory];
<< preprocessed.mx
```

5) Create your Manipulate:

```
Manipulate[
    ListPlot[lpFunc[eps, om0, omf, A][[-1, 1]], ImageSize -> Medium, 
        PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0035]],
    {{eps, 3., ε}, 1, 5},
    {{om0, 1., ω0}, 1, 5},
    {{omf, 1.7, ω0f}, 0, 5},
    {{A, 5.}, 1, 10}
]
```

This will be now a nice *Manipulate* experience, where your plot will change smoothly. Something you can show.

**Update End**

By the way. I've had ancient greek at school and it gives me bad memories if someone is using greek letters (although not as bad as the memories for latin...phew)

[Please have a look at this post where some of the authorities here made decent effort on importing unicode letters. Another nice hint from @cormullion...What I'd do without him...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook)

I hope this helps or at least gives an idea for what you try to achieve.

**Update 2: Gain Extra Speed in Prep**

Since the function takes numbers and produces numbers, you can compile it as a numeric function into C. Which makes it FAR faster. Do it so:

```
cFunc = 
  Compile[{eps, om0, omf, A}, 
   Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] == 
       eps (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - om0^2*x[t] + A*Sin[omf*t], x[0] == 1, 
      x'[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 Pi/omf] == 0, Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 
      10000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
lpFunc[eps_, om0_, omf_, A_] := lpFunc[eps, om0, omf, A] = cFunc[eps, om0, omf, A];
```

I'm seeing a 2-3X improvement in speed of original data generation.

**End Update**

Comment: Re: greek; also see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/how-to-copy-as-unicode-from-a-notebook)

Comment: Thanks :) didn't knew they've made progress on that matter. I failed utterly porting @Mr.Wizard's entry to use pbcopy (for Mac), so I gave up on Unicode. Will check it, although there are bad memories concerning Homer and Hexameter ;)

Comment: @rcollyer your edit is simply amazing. thank you for that...totally lost Compile out of sight when i wrote this. thanks a lot. now this post seems to be pretty decent. what do you think?

Comment: Hey, if it was my doing, I'd gladly take credit. But, alas and alack, I merely fixed up someone else's stuff. Blame them. :)

Comment: yep, sorry, guilty as charged. :-) If I see a good place to plug in Parallelize or Compile, I can't help myself. :-)

Comment: @GregoryKlopper `NDSolve` is not compilable. I didn't try it, but are you really sure you see a performance improvement, given that the compiled function immediately calls back out of the VM to evaluate the top-level code? If you've been experimenting, you might easily have some memoized definitions still hanging around, and thus fool yourself over its actual performance.

Comment: When I memorize the definitions, the answer gets back in <<1sec. When I do not, the difference in time is 2-3 fold, but still 10-30 seconds. Not sure how to explain it. Wonder if CompilationTarget->"C" has anything to do with it?

Comment: @GregoryKlopper ok. so if you found out compile does really help here, or it was just the memoized effect we might update this post....

Comment: My tests show, as I commented above, that it really does have an effect on speed. As any good science experiment, it should be repeatable by others. I invite someone to copy-paste the code, and confirm their timings. I used Remove@lpFunc before every re-assignment of lpFunc to do the testing, but I don't remember if I killed the kernel or didn't. Shouldn't matter. One can hardly mistaken 15 seconds for 0.01s, can they? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you wanted to accomplish. Good luck!

```
Manipulate[
 test = Reap[
    NDSolve[{x''[
        t] == ε (1 - x[t]^2) x'[t] - ω0^2*x[t] + 
        A*Sin[ωf*t], x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 π/ωf] == 0, 
       Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 10000}, 
     MaxSteps -> ∞]][[-1, 1]];
 ListPlot[test, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0035]]
 , {{ε, 3}, 1, 5}
 , {{ω0, 1}, 1, 5}
 , {{ωf, 1.788}, 0, 5}
 , {{A, 5}, 1, 10}]
```