# How do I save a Unicode string?

Tags: export, output-formatting, unicode

I am having a problem saving a long complicated string with Unicode characters in it.  I have boiled the problem down, I think, to this minimal example:

```
hw = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 8594, 32, 
    87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33};
str = FromCharacterCode[hw]
```

which assigns a *hello world* string with a right arrow (the Unicode 8594 character) to `str`.  If I then

```
ExportString[str, "Text"]
```

I get a different string, as the second line in

[image: right and wrong hello world strings]

instead of the first line.  I have a program that reads cells from a Notebook and custom converts it to a LaTeX string.  I just cannot save the string.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: [How to “Copy as Unicode” from a Notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/121)

Comment: What is the logic of the junk ExportString prints into a cell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct character encoding for `Export` may help.

```
Export["hello.txt", str, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]
```

does the trick for me:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks.  Did not know `Export` accepted character encodings.

Answer (score 3):

Hbar asked:

> What is the logic of the junk ExportString prints into a cell?

On my system (*Mathematica* 7, Windows 7) I don't get quite the same result, but I assume the mechanism is similar.  If we use `ToCharacterCode` to convert our intended string into UTF-8 we get multi-byte encoding:

```
utf8 = ToCharacterCode["Hello \[RightArrow] World!", "UTF8"]
```

> ```
> {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 226, 134, 146, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33}
> ```

However when we convert this to a string using default encoding we do not get the original:

```
FromCharacterCode[utf8]
```

> ```
> "Hello â World!"
> ```

This is what I get when I use `ExportString[str, "Text"]` as shown in the question.  I assume that a similar conversion is taking place.

Comment: I'm using MMA 9 on a Mac and this explains what I see.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to write latex, why not use "Tex" export which gives nice looking Latex

```
hw = {72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 8594, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33};
str = FromCharacterCode[hw];
ExportString[str, "Tex"]
```

[image]

or more simply

```
TeXForm[str]
\text{Hello $\rightarrow $ World!}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer.  I would like to use the listings package for Input cells instead of line-by-line pmbs.  Also, Mathematica notebooks have more structure than LaTeX, so they are easier to pre-process, allowing me to have cells marked latex, process grids as tabular when needed,  ignore closed cells, etc.

Comment: Sorry Hbar, but I have never used the listings package and don't know that pmbs is. I just was trying to give an easy way to "read from a Notebook and convert to a Latex string".

Comment: listings is a LaTeX package that helps one pretty-print programs and pmb (poor man's bold) is a macro from the TeXbook that creates bold characters by printing three slightly offset copies of its argument.