# Join lists with nested list

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way of smarter way of joining list of the form

```
l1 = {a,{b,c}};
l2 = {d,{e,f}};
l3 = {g,{h,i}};
```

To obtain

```
{a,d,g,{b,c,e,f,h,i}}
```

The code I have is

```
 {Sequence @@ #1, Flatten[#2]} & @@  Transpose[{l1, l2, l3}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this

```
MapThread[Join, {l1, l2, l3}] /. Join -> Sequence
```

> {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}

Answer (score 9):

This seems like a good way:

```
l1 = {a, {b, c}};
l2 = {d, {e, f}};
l3 = {g, {h, i}};

Apply[Sequence, Thread@{l1, l2, l3}, {-2}]

(* Out: {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}} *)
```

---

It's been a few days, but I got distracted this morning from work and revisited this... My reward was seeing [poetry](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60714/117) (+1 btw), but I also killed a couple minutes running some timings on a sampling of the various answers:

```
ClearAll@t;
SetAttributes[t, HoldFirst];
t[e_, n_] := First@AbsoluteTiming[Do[e, {n}];]
```

OP:

```
t[
 {Sequence @@ #1, Flatten[#2]} & @@ Transpose[{l1, l2, l3}],
 10^6
 ]

(* Out: 3.849385 *)
```

This answer:

```
t[
 Apply[Sequence, Thread@{l1, l2, l3}, {-2}],
 10^6
 ]

(* Out: 2.882288 *)
```

Snapshot of a few other answers:

```
t[
 MapThread[Join, {l1, l2, l3}] /. Join -> Sequence,
 10^6
 ]

(* Out: 5.532553 *)

t[
 MapAt[Sequence @@ # &, Transpose[{l1, l2, l3}], {{1}, {2, All}}],
 10^6
 ]

(* Out: 6.293629 *)

t[
 FlattenAt[Flatten /@ Transpose[{l1, l2, l3}], 1],
 10^6
 ]

(* Out: 3.969397*)
```

(Performance of this operation is probably irrelevant for the OP's purposes, but I always enjoy playing on the performance side of things.)

Comment: Whats the -2 doing in this case?

Comment: @GordonCoale [ref/Apply, Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html): "A negative level `-n` consists of all parts of `expr` with depth `n`." See [ref/Depth](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Depth.html) for more explanation.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is "smarter". Anyway:

```
ClearAll@k; SetAttributes[k, Listable];
k @@ {l1, l2, l3} /. k -> Sequence
(* {a, d, g, {b, e, h, c, f, i}} *)
```

Comment: I think the output OP asking for is `{a,d,g,{b,c,e,f,h,i}}` (Why he accepted this 囧 ?)

Answer (score 6):

```
♯ = {## & @@ #, ## & @@@ #2} & @@ ({##}) & ;

♯[l1, l2, l3]
(* {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}} *)
```

See also: [`♭ = ## & @@@ (## & @@@ {## & @@@ # & /@ #} & /@ #) &`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78050/125)

Comment: Look, Ma! No letters! +1.  You could even replace `m` with `\[FivePointedStar]`.

Comment: thank you @Michael; updated with something along those lines.

Comment: This is evil.  I approve.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, somehow i knew you would:)  How do you get the `\[Sharp]` typeset as `♯`?

Comment: [(1137)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/121)

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard -- i will keep that function handy.

Comment: Yep, I can imagine in a near future `#~♯~# == 42`. @Mr.Wizard remember to give attribution.

Comment: kguler, while it does copy and paste correctly the `\[Transpose]` unicode symbol uses a private glyph (as I recall) therefore it will not appear correct in (most?) web browsers.  This may not matter to you in this particular case but in general it should not be used.  @belisarius All joking aside I really don't try to write opaque code. :-p

Answer (score 5):

My take:

```
MapAt[Sequence @@ # &, Transpose[{l1, l2, l3}], {{1}, {2, All}}]
```

> ```
> {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This is another way:

```
FlattenAt[Flatten /@ Transpose[{l1, l2, l3}], 1]
```

> {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}

Answer (score 4):

One option:

```
l1 + l2 + l3 /. Plus -> Sequence
```

> {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Tks!.. Now I have a nice one.

Comment: Indeed you do.  Probably not as general as would be best, but then again neither are several other answers, and the OP never really specified the problem. +1

Comment: Similar but more abusive: `Re[l1, l2, l3] /. Re@x__ :> x`

Comment: This answer has the same spirit as belisarius's, so does the output: it outputs `{a, d, g, {b, e, h, c, f, i}}` rather than  `{a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}`.

Answer (score 3):

Two very intuitive ways. First the *Flattinator*:

```
#2[#1[#1 /@ #1[{##3}, {2}], {1}], 1] &[Flatten, FlattenAt, l1, l2, l3]
```

and here the *Padding-Miss-User*

```
PadLeft[{Flatten[#2]}, 4, RotateLeft[#1]] & @@ Transpose[{l1, l2, l3}]
```

(Please don't use them. Just look and shake your head)

Comment: +1 But can't help frowning while shaking my head :)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```
Transpose @ {l1, l2, l3} /. a:{__Symbol} :> Sequence @@ a
```

> {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}

Original answer:

```
Append[First /@ #, Flatten[Last /@ #]] & [{l1, l2, l3}]
```

> {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}

Comment: The desired output is `{a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}` :D

Answer (score 2):

Rule based alternatives for completeness sake:

```
{l1, l2, l3} //. {{a__, {b__}}, {c_, {d__}}, 
    rest : {_, {__}} ...} :> {{a, c, {b, d}}, rest} // First
```

> `{a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}`

And:

```
Flatten[{l1, l2, l3}, {2, 1}] /. {start__, rest : {_, _} ...} :> {start, Join[rest]}
```

> `{a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}}`

Comment: Ha! I was tempted too :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :

```
Join[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] &@(Flatten /@ Transpose@{l1, l2, l3})
(* {a, d, g, {b, c, e, f, h, i}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add something for general case:

```
l1 = {a, h, u, {b, t, c}};
l2 = {d, e, t, y, {e, f}};
l3 = {g, {h, i}};

Append @@ ({Cases[#, _?(Head[#] =!= List &)], 
     Flatten[Cases[#, _List]]} &[Flatten[{l1, l2, l3}, 1]])

(*{a, h, u, d, e, t, y, g, {b, t, c, e, f, h, i}}*)
```