# Flatten nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list as follows

```
lis= {a, {{{b}, {c,d,e}}, {{f}, {g,h,i}}}}
```

which I would like to flatten to

```
flattenLis={a,{b,c,d,e},{f,g,h,i}}
```

Does anyone have a hint. All my flatten attempts did not work. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Here is an approach where I apply the flattening "from the bottom up" (negative level specification). This works by operating on `{lis}` instead of `lis`, in order to have sufficiently many levels even when there's no list wrapping an element, such as `a`:

```
Flatten[Map[Flatten, {lis}, {-3}], 2]

(* ==> {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}} *)
```

My approach also works for this example:

```
lis2 = {a, {{{b}, {c, d, e}}, {{f}, {g, h, i}}}, b};

Flatten[Map[Flatten, {lis2}, {-3}], 2]

(* ==> {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}, b} *)
```

Comment: According your idea, `{#1, Sequence @@ #2} & @@ Map[Flatten, lis, {-3}]` also works:)

Comment: There is a potential problem with this approach.  This will fail if the elements are not atomic, e.g. if `b = Sqrt[2];`.  My method does not fail in that circumstance, nor does it fail on `lis2` despite your assertion.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, the bottom-up approach can only work if the leafs are atomic - I guess maybe one could ensure that using `Block` if the entries are at least named by symbols that can be blocked.

Comment: @ShutaoTang Yes, but your `Slot` based approach wouldn't work with my `lis2`. Anyway, at this point the OP certainly has a lot of methods to choose from...

Answer (score 10):

Not sure how general it will be:

```
{#, ## & @@ Flatten /@ #2} & @@ lis
```

> ```
> {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}}
> ```

Comment: Same comment here as for @Mr.Wizard.

Comment: Could you @Kuba give some explanation here? :).

Comment: I see. 1) ` {#1, Flatten /@ #2} & @@ lis(*==>{a, {{b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}}}*)`   2) `{#, ## & @@ #2} & @@ %  (*==> {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}}*)`

Comment: @Jens sure but that is not the question. :)

Answer (score 8):

One approach:

```
MapAt[Flatten, lis, {2, All}] ~FlattenAt~ 2
```

> ```
> {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}}
> ```

Hopefully some combination of [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html), [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html), and [`FlattenAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlattenAt.html) will work for any structure you have.

Comment: This works for the example, but not for `lis = {a, {{{b}, {c, d, e}}, {{f}, {g, h, i}}}, b}`. I upvoted anyway, since the question doesn't specify what generalizations are desirable.

Comment: I discovered that this solution was restricted in  V8.`MapAt::psl: "Position specification {2,All} in MapAt[Flatten,{a,{{{b},{c,d,e}},{{f},{g,h,i}}}},{2,All}] is not an integer or a list of integers. "`

Comment: @ShutaoTang That is correct; support for `All` and `Span` within `MapAt` was (silently) introduced in version 9; see: [(31173)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31173/121).  There are alternatives in that Q&A that will work in earlier versions.

Comment: @Jens I'm not sure what you mean; using your `lis` I get `{a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}, b}` -- what else do you want?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, I know what happened: I was on MMA version 8, and tested my `lis2` with your method. It errored out, but now I see it works in version 10. In version 8, your answer doesn't even work with the original `lis`... It's because `MapAt` in version 8 doesn't seem to accept position specification `All`. That change isn't mentioned in the version-10 documentation.

Answer (score 7):

Also:

```
lis = {a, {{{b}, {c, d, e}}, {{f}, {g, h, i}}}};
Fold[Apply[## &, #, {#2}] &, lis, {1, 2}]
(* {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}} *)
```

And ... [`♯ = {## & @@ #, ## & @@@ #2} & @@ ({##}) &`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60714/125)'s close relative:

```
♭ = ## & @@@ (## & @@@ {## & @@@ # & /@ #} & /@ #) &;
```

Examples:

```
♭ @ lis
(* {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}} *)

lis2 = {a, {{{b}, {c, d, e}}, {{f}, {g, h, i}, {x}}}, b};
♭ @ lis2
{a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i, x}, b}
```

Comment: Your last one is probably a quote from the pirate in Asterix&Obelix, right? But it doesn't work on `lis = {a, {{{b}, {c, d, e}}, {{f}, {g, h, i}}}, b}`.

Comment: @Jens, right! and  Getafix says there is a fix:)

Comment: If anyone looks at the edit history, they will get dizzy... I could still annoy you with this example, though: `lis = {a, {{{b}, {c, d, e}}, {{f}, {g, h, i}, {x}}}, b};` where I added an `{x}` together with the `{f}`. Your first approach works, the second still doesn't.

Comment: @Jens, deleted the quotes from the pirate and getafix:) Actually, i am surprised the first one works  beyond op's simple example.

Comment: I didn't really intend to make you delete the other solution - it was fun to look at...

Comment: @jens, don't worry. The reason i deleted was i was getting dizzy myself; and (although I think the modified version does handle your second example)  i wasn't quite sure if it would be able to handle the upcoming one:) I had another just-as-silly "Look Ma! No letters!"  function in another  q/a with `\[Sharp]` (`\[Flat]`s cousin)  but i cannot find it now.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is rule replacement, which can be restricted to a specific level.

```
In[16]:=Replace[lis, l_List :> Sequence @@ Flatten[l], {1}] === flattenList

Out[16]=True
```

I didn't see an easy way to make this one work without `Sequence`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I really understand how the example is to be generalised, but this removes all `List` heads at level 2 and 4:

```
ReplacePart[lis, Position[lis, List, {#}] & /@ Join[2, 4] -> Sequence]

(* {a, {b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, i}} *)
```