# How to make FlattenAt work with Span?

Tags: list-manipulation

This works:

```
MapAt[h, {a, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, 2 ;; 3]

(* {a, h[{b, c}], h[{d, e}], {f}} *)
```

but this doesn't:

```
FlattenAt[h, {a, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, 2 ;; 3]
```

> FlattenAt::argt: FlattenAt called with 3 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected. >>

What is a performant way to make a custom flattenAt function that works on the same position arguments as MapAt?

Comment: What about something like `MapAt[Apply@Sequence, {a, {b, c}, {d, e}, f}, 2 ;; 3]`?

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin, I really like the solution from your comment; you should post it as an answer. The custom `FlattenAt` function from my answer seems to be a bit faster though, especially for a long list of positions.

Comment: @Sascha Ok, why not. Posted.

Comment: @Leonid As I'm sure you know `Apply` will not work inside a held expression so this is not equivalent to `FlattenAt`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I actually pretty much never use `FlattenAt`, so wasn't aware that it works inside held expressions - which is of course natural to expect once we think about it (in fact didn't even think in that direction, since typically my uses of held code and `Flatten` don't overlap). But that's a good point. I will make a note in my answer. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 6):

```
FlattenSpan[li_, sp_Span] :=
 FlattenAt[li, List /@ Range @@ sp]

FlattenSpan[{{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, 2 ;; 3]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. If the list of positions is long, `Transpose[{Range@@sp}]` will be vastly more efficient than `List /@ Range @@ sp`.

Comment: You could use `List /@ Range[Length@li][[sp]]` to accommodate `All` and negative positions in the span.

Comment: @Leonid and `Partition[Range @@ sp, 1]` will be more efficient still. ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Interesting. Never thought of that. I do use this sort of code in a number of places, so will at some point check the difference and perhaps adopt this method. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Leonid Sincerely glad if I can help, but I was mostly just having some fun.  Frankly since I have seen the performance of various methods trade places between versions I have mostly stopped this kind of "micro benchmarking" as it is ephemeral knowledge.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I stopped doing that too, long ago, and for the same reason. Besides, in any large program (or even not so large), typically the bottlenecks are elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a version of `FlattenAt` - like function based on `MapAt` and `Sequence`, which seems to work as you requested:

```
ClearAll[flattenAt];
flattenAt[expr_, spec_] := MapAt[Apply@Sequence, expr, spec]
```

It returns the mostly same results as built-in `FlattenAt` on standard position specs, and also works with `Span` via `MapAt`.

As noted by Mr.Wizard, one place where it differs from the `FlattenAt` when one wants to `Flatten` inside held expressions, which the real `FlattenAt` does, while my version doesn't.

Comment: Could you compare the different answers in terms of performance? Currently I am limited to using the programming cloud and I don't know how representative this is.

Comment: @Sascha Sorry, I am short of time right now. Later, if time permits and no one does that by then.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, it seems not working with degenerate cases like `flattenAt[{{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, {{ ;; }, { ;; }}]`

Comment: @garej It is not clear to me how it *should* work for such a level spec.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. it seems reasonable that it should work the same way as `MapAt[h, {a, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, {{ ;; }, { ;; }}]` works, where `h` should behave as it had `Flat` Attribute. I'm just learning so not able to implement that sort of things. I was able just to use very slow `MapIndexed` for similar task (you may see modest attempt below).

Comment: @garej I see. In this case, one can e.g. define a helper function as follows: `ClearAll[fl]; fl[arg_] := Sequence @@ arg; fl[args___] := args;`, and then `flattenAt[expr_, spec_] := MapAt[fl, expr, spec]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. that is what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

<s>I didn't really test how fast this implementation is (feel free to do so and modify if you know something better) but</s>  It is as fast as the regular `FlattenAt` and it handles all* cases of `Span`.

```
Clear[flattenSpan, list]

flattenSpan[list_, span_]:=Module[{range},
range = span /. All-> Length@list 
/.{Span[a_,b_] /;b<a :>Table[{i}, {i,a,Length@list+b}],
   Span[a_,b_] :> Table[{i}, {i, a, b}], 
   Span[a_,b_, c_] /; b<a :>Table[{i}, {i, a,Length@list+ b, c}],      
   Span[a_,b_, c_] :>Table[{i}, {i, a, b, c}]};

FlattenAt[list, range]
]
```

Examples: for `list = {{a}, {b,c}, {d, e}, {f}, {g, h,i}, {j}, {k, l}}`

```
flattenSpan[list, 2;;] (* flattens all elements starting from the second*)
(* {{a},b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l} *) 

flattenSpan[list, ;;;;2]  (* flattens every second element*)
(* {a,{b,c},d,e,{f},g,h,i,{j},k,l} *)

flattenSpan[list, 1;;4;;2] (* flattens every second element between 1 and 4*)
(* {a,{b,c},d,e,{f},{g,h,i},{j},{k,l}} *)

flattenSpan[list, ;;] (* flattens all elements*)
(* {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l} *)
```

negative indices work as well with one little caveat*: to flatten the last 4 entries in the list one has to use `-4;;-1` whereas in `MapAt` `-4;;` would suffice.

```
flattenSpan[list, -4;;-1]       (* flattens the last 4 elements*)
(* {{a},{b,c},{d,e},f,g,h,i,j,k,l} *)
```

Fixed the issue mentioned in the comment

```
flattenSpan[list, 1;;-2] (*flattens all elements from 1 to the second-last*)
(* {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,{j},{k,l}} *)
```

Comment: try `flattenSpan[list, 2 ;; -1]`

Comment: @garej you are right, I included rules to fix that. The behavior for `-4;;` as explained at the bottom still persists though

Comment: @Sasha, try `list = {a, {b,c}, {d, e}, {f}` with span `;;2`. Seems like `FlattenAt` weakness not to working with atoms like `a` persists.

Comment: @Sasha, try list with atom element, like `{a, {b, c}, {}, {{d}, e}, {f}, {a}, {f}}`

Comment: @garej both `FlattenAt` and `Flatten` don't handle atoms gracefully. In my humble opinion the implementation should be that `Flatten[atom]` evaluates to `atom`. See [this question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78030/flatten-nested-lists).

Comment: read OP: "works on the same position arguments as MapAt". what is the logic to have a function that avoid atoms with spans?

Comment: @garej I think my solution gives what the OP asked for. Dealing with atoms inside `FlattenAt` is another problem entirely and has nothing do to with modifying `FlattenAt` to take spans as third argument.

Comment: I like your solution but it does not. even without atoms. Compare: `MapAt[h, {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, 1 ;; -1] ==  MapAt[h, {{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, ;;]` and yours `flattenSpan[{{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, 1 ;; -1] ==  flattenSpan[{{a}, {b, c}, {d, e}, {f}}, ;;]`. may be you will see what I was trying to say ;)) anyway, let us stop for now...

Answer (score 3):

The version of "classic" `FlattenAt` that does not work with atom elements but works with arguments of `MapAt` function in different forms:

```
flatAt[list_, span_Span] := 
  FlattenAt[list, MapIndexed[#2 &, list][[span]]];
flatAt[list_List, span_List /; Length[span] <= 1] := 
  FlattenAt[list, MapIndexed[#2 &, list][[span[[1]]]]];
flatAt[list_, span_List /; Length[span] > 1] := 
  FlattenAt[list, 
   Union @@ 
    Table[MapIndexed[#2 &, list][[span[[i, 1]]]], {i, Length[span]}]];
```

Examples with sample `listok = {{a}, {b, c}, {}, {{d}, e}, {f}, {a}, {f}}`:

```
flatAt[listok, {{-1 ;;}, { ;; }, {;; 2}}]
```

> {a, b, c, {d}, e, f, a, f}

```
flatAt[listok, {1 ;; }]
```

> {a, b, c, {d}, e, f, a, f}

```
flatAt[listok, 1 ;; -1]
```

> {a, b, c, {d}, e, f, a, f}