# Different results between V9 and V10 when using Style with Listplot

Tags: plotting, style

Consider this example:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];
ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, PointSize[Abs[#2]/50], Hue[#2]] & @@@ data]
```

the results from V9 and V10 are as follows:

**V9**
[image]

**V10**
[image]

It looks like two layers of points have been generated in V10 (one with style and the other without style).

Any explanation for this and how to make the result of V10 similar to that of V9?

Thanks

Comment: I notice that you have not Accepted an answer to this question.  Are you unsatisfied by any of the explanations and work-arounds given?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I almost forgot about this question :)

Comment: Well, thank you.  I wasn't meaning to complain, just checking in.  When I don't Accept any answer it's usually because, no matter how good the existing ones are, I am hoping for something more.  For example people tried darn hard for me on [(1137)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/121) but a convenient platform-independent solution still seems slightly out of reach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that the points are being rendered twice, as can be seen with:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -1.3, -0.4, 0.1}];
g1 = ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, PointSize[Abs[#2]/50], Hue[#2]] & @@@ data];

First[g1]
```

[image]

Note that there is a `Point` expression with all the points followed by individually styled `Point` expressions which render in color in this output.

A bit of spelunking shows that `Style` is but one of many wrappers handled by `ListPlot`.  When non-numeric data is passed this function is called:

```
Charting`ListPlotParser
```

With a definition including:

```
  ...
    Charting`ParserDump`initPList[model,SystemWrappers];
    Charting`ParserDump`initPList[model,ApplicationWrappers];
    Charting`ParserDump`initPList[model,MetaWrappers];
    Charting`ParserDump`initPList[model,ModelWrappers];
    Charting`ParserDump`initPList[model,QuantityWrappers];
    Charting`ParserDump`initPList[model,ErrorWrappers];
  ...
```

Later the function `` Charting`ParserDump`stripWrappers `` is used, from which we may find the definitions:

```
Definition @@ Names["Charting`ParserDump`$*WrapperPattern"]

Charting`ParserDump`$ApplicationWrapperPattern =
  Charting`Highlighted | Labeled | Charting`Tweaked | Legended | Style | Placed

Charting`ParserDump`$ErrorWrapperPattern = PlusMinus | Charting`ErrorBar

Charting`ParserDump`$MetaWrapperPattern = Alternatives[Rule]

Charting`ParserDump`$ModelWrapperPattern = EventData | WeightedData

Charting`ParserDump`$SystemWrapperPattern =
  Annotation | Button | EventHandler | Hyperlink | Mouseover | PopupWindow | StatusArea | Tooltip
```

And later still the styling is apparently added back with something like:

> ```
> System`ProtoPlotDump`modelData$15013["ApplicationWrappers", "Add", {2} -> {Style, 
>   RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}]
> ```

**The point of all this rambling** is that it seems the wrapper system has been greatly extended to handle many different heads, including ones that are intended to *add to* rather than replace plot points.  Because of this it seems an edge case was created where the persistence of the original points is undesirable.

The complexity of this system makes it difficult to propose a general solution.  If *all* points are going to be `Style` wrapped then you can simply remove the first `Point` object as Michael shows, or set the `PlotStyle` to `PointSize[0]` as Brett shows, but if only some of your points are `Style` wrapped this will not work as intended.

I cannot yet imagine how this will interact with the many different wrappers recognized by `ListPlot` but for the case of `Style` alone I think it is appropriate to filter out any points from the first `Point` expression that also appear later in a `Style` expression:

```
fixStyleWrappers =
  {{a___, {b___, Point[p : {__}]}, c___}, sty : {__}} :>
   With[{filtered = 
      DeleteCases[p, 
       Alternatives @@ Cases[sty, Style[{Point[{d : {_, _}}]}, ___] :> d, -1]]},
     {{a, {b, Point @ filtered}, c}, sty}
   ];
```

Example:

```
ListPlot[{0.1, Style[0.3, Red, AbsolutePointSize[5]], 0.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[12]] /. fixStyleWrappers
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you look closely at V9 you'll see that it does the same thing, except that the points are darker, smaller, and generally not as obvious:

[image]

The easiest way to get rid of this is to make the points very small:

```
ListPlot[..., PlotStyle -> PointSize[0]]
```

[image]

Comment: So is it correct that two layers of points are plotted? if yes can you elaborate on that in you answer.

Comment: I would prefer that they weren't duplicated, but they are probably serving a purpose that isn't obvious. I believe they only show up with `Style` and perhaps a few other wrappers.

Comment: @Brett Do you feel that this behavior is *not* a bug?  It seems like one, though quite understandable. (Assuming my analysis is correct.)  Should I tag the question with `bugs` or not?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with `PlotThemes` plotting points below your "styled" points. You can override this with `PlotTheme->"None"` (throws an error but works), or you can just use `Graphics` and skip the whole `PlotTheme` business anyway:

```
Graphics[Style[Point[{#1, #2}], PointSize[Abs[#2]/50], Hue[#2]] & @@@ 
 data, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` is the best way to get back to V9 behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The OP's analysis of what it looks like seems to be exactly right.  I think it must be a bug.  A (sort of ugly) workaround is to removed the unstyled points:

```
ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, PointSize[Abs[#2]/50], Hue[#2]] & @@@ 
   data] /. Point[{{_, _}, {_, _} ..}] -> {}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

In version 9, `PlotStyle->PointSize[0]` or `BaseStyle->PointSize[0]` does not get rid of those dots. They become visible when you set the opacity to less then 1.

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}];
ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, PointSize[Abs[#2]/50], Directive[Opacity[.5], Hue[#2]]] & @@@ data, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0]]
```

[image]

Two additional work-arounds are (1) to set the value of the `PlotMarkers` option to an empty `String` or an empty `Graphic`, or (2) use `PlotStyle -> Opacity[0]`:

```
ListPlot[Style[{#1, #2}, PointSize[Abs[#2]/50], 
    Directive[Opacity[.5], Hue[#2]]] & @@@ data, PlotMarkers -> ""]
(* or PlotMarkers ->Graphics[{}]  or PlotStyle->Opacity[] *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So many great answers here, just thought I'd throw out there that another way to get a plot like OP's is to use the function [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html)

```
BubbleChart[Table[{x, x^2, x^2/5}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}],
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[#2] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 BubbleSizes -> {.1^2, 2^2}/30,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]