# PlotMarkers shadows the settings by Style

Tags: plotting, style

The code below gives color-varying points with explicit Style wrappers:

```
ListPlot[Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi,Pi/20}],PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image]

However, when I want to change the marker shape with `PlotMarkers`, the color settings are shadowed with default color:

```
ListPlot[Table[  Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

My questions are:

1. Can such behavior be considered as a bug?
2. What is the workaround for changing to another marker?

Comment: related [Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60929/125)

Comment: On a scale of 0 (feature) to 10 (bug), this is probably an 8. (It's not what I'd expect, but there may be some good reason for it, and it doesn't entirely surprise me.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit** 
My previous answer was just a workaround, and it involved putting the color as a graphics directive for the individual plotmarkers.

My thanks to @rcollyer for bringing an undocumented option to my attention which is the true solution to this problem.  You just need to set `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}`

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I might wait for one day to see if more opinions can appear.

Comment: The edit is great! It also reminds me that how many undocumented features are there to explore!