# ListPlot with colors

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Let's create some sample data

```
n = 100;
d00 = Table[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-4, 4}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 1, n}];
```

Now I want the following: create a list plot with the first element of the list as $x$ coordinate and the third element as the $y$ coordinate.

```
d0 = Table[{d00[[i, 1]], d00[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, Length[d00]}];
```

The color of each point is controlled by the corresponding second element. In particular, if the real number is between -2 and 2 the point should be green, while if it is lower/equal than -2 or greater/equal than 2 the point should be red.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
l = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {200, 3}];

 ListPlot[
 List /@ (l[[All, {1, 3}]])
 , PlotStyle -> (If[Abs[#[[2]]] < 2, Green, Red] & /@ l)
 ]
```

Where you can use any function that returns a color in your styling. You might want have to rescale your data if it's not in the range {0,1}.

[image]

If you want to change point sizes you can use `Directive`

```
ListPlot[
 List /@ (l[[All, {1, 3}]])
 , PlotStyle -> (If[Abs[#[[2]]] < 2, 
      Directive[Green, PointSize[0.04]], Red] & /@ l)
 ]
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Basically a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105574/plotmarkers-shadows-the-settings-by-style).

You can just style each point before you pass them to `ListPlot` for things like this.

Define a color function:

```
cfun = Piecewise[{{White, # <= -2}, {Green, -2 < # < 2}, {Red, # > 2}}, Black] &
```

Then style by second element:

```
d0 = Table[Style[{d00[[i, 1]], d00[[i, 3]]}, cfun[d00[[i, 2]]]], {i, 1, Length[d00]}];

ListPlot[d0, Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.5]]
```

[image]

**Also Specifying PlotMarkers**

Using the `PlotMarkers` option will mask the `Style` definitions, unless you specify the undocumented:

```
Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}
```

Like so:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  ListPlot[d0, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}],
  ListPlot[d0, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 5}, Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! And if I want to control the size of the points?

Comment: Heh, yeah, using the `PlotMarkers` option will mask the `Style` specifications. Instead you can use `PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03]`

Comment: If I use `ListPlot[d0, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]` then around each red and green dot there is a blue circle!

Comment: How strange, I don't see that. Regardless, a more robust fix appears to be to set `Method -> {"OptimizePlotMarkers" -> False}` then you can actually use `PlotMarkers` as normal.

Comment: Now you lost me! Can you make an edit?

Answer (score 2):

Just some variants:

```
l = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {200, 3}];
With[{g = #[[All, {1, 3}]] & /@ GatherBy[l, #[[2]] < 2 &]},
 ListPlot[g, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]]
ListPlot[Last@Reap[Sow[{#1, #3}, #2 < 2] & @@@ l, _, #2 &], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]
ListPlot[GroupBy[l, #[[2]] < 2 &, #[[All, {1, 3}]] &], 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 8}]
```

Outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use `Graphics` which gives you more control over your plot.

```
n = 100;
d00 = Table[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-4, 4}], 
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 1, n}];


{x1, x2} = {Min[#], Max[#]} &@d00[[All, 2]];
col[x_] := If[Abs[x] < 2, Green, Red]  (*for color*)
scale[x_] := (x - x1)/(x2 - x1)/20     (*for point size*)
Graphics[{col[#[[2]]], Disk[#[[{1, 3}]], scale[#[[2]]]]} & /@ d00, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**ListPlot with styled data**

```
styleddata1 = With[{ps = Rescale[#2, Through[{Min, Max}@d00[[All, 2]]], {5, 20}]},
    Style[Tooltip[{#, #3}, #2], If[-2 <= #2 <= 2, Directive[Green, AbsolutePointSize[ps]], 
       Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[ps]]]]] & @@@ d00;

ListPlot[styleddata1, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**BubbleChart with styled data**

```
styleddata2 = Style[Tooltip[{#, #3,
         Rescale[#2, Through[{Min, Max}@d00[[All, 2]]], {0.05, 1}]}, #2], 
         If[-2 <= #2 <= 2, Green, Red]] & @@@ d00;

BubbleChart[styleddata2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]