# ErrorListPlot ignores some exact data points

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Possible bug? Or am I missing something / expecting too much?

Forgive the seemingly obscure data points but they're where I've noticed a problem.

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
data = {
   {{(10 π)/8, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]},
   {{(11 π)/8, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]},
   {{(12 π)/8, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]}
   };
```

`ErrorListPlot` won't plot the error bar at x = 11 Pi/8 unless the datapoint is first converted to a numerical value:

```
ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{3, 5}, All}]
```

[image]

```
ErrorListPlot[N@data, PlotRange -> {{3, 5}, All}]
```

[image]

What gives?

Comment: Definitely a bug, and a weird one.  Shorter test code to see the result, `Needs["ErrorBarPlots\`"];
ErrorListPlot[{{{(# π)/8, 1}, ErrorBar[0.2]}}] & /@ {10, 11, 11.0,
   12}`.  Seems to affect versions 10.x, but works as expected in version 9.

Comment: Added the version-10 tag  Confirmed what @JasonB said before: works OK on v9

Answer (score 5):

(All observations apply to version 10.1.0.)

`ErrorListPlot` is written in as a rather straightforward post-processing of `ListPlot`, with error bar values first assigned to and then retrieved from a definition upon `` ErrorBarPlots`Private`error `` (hereafter notated `error`).  A definition is made as a side-effect within a replacement rule:

```
{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, e_?NumericQ} :>
  (error[N[{x, y}]] = ErrorBar[{0, 0}, {-1*e, e}]; {x, y})
```

Note that `N[{x, y}]` is used for the definition but `{x, y}` is the actual result of the replacement, and this expression is later passed to `ListPlot`.

After `ListPlot` post-processing it is applied to point coordinates which includes:

```
{l, (ebfunc[#1, error[#1]] &) /@ Cases[l, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, ∞]}
```

Where `l` is a `Line` or `Point` expression in the plot returned by `ListPlot` as matched by `ReplaceAll`.

Making assignments upon numeric values is always a little bit fragile.  Here the assumption is that `ListPlot` will numericize the values plotted in exactly the same way as `N[{x, y}]` and not modify them further in any way, and it appears that assumption is false.

A "quick fix" for this problem is to apply `N` to the argument passed to `ListPlot` within the definition of `ErrorListPlot`, which may be patched with:

```
With[{dv := DownValues[ErrorListPlot]},
  dv = dv /. (lp : ListPlot)[a_, x___] :> lp[N @ a, x];
]

ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {{3, 5}, All}]
```

[image]

However this *still* makes the assumption that numeric values passed to `ListPlot` will appear unchanged in the output `Graphics` expression, and I don't know if that can be assured now and in the future.  I feel that `ErrorListPlot` should have been written differently, using a wrapper like [`Annotation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotation.html) as shown in [Coloring Points in a Plot, based on their position in the list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21130/coloring-points-in-a-plot-based-on-their-position-in-the-list/21133#21133).

Strangely [prior exploration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60944/121) indicated that `ListPlot` is already set up to use `` Charting`ErrorBar `` as a wrapper (like `Annotation`).  Perhaps this has been implemented in more recent versions? (I am still using 10.1.0 as noted earlier.)

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful insights! It's always interesting (and informative) to peek beneath the hood.