# Problems when solving a nonlinear PDE system with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, code-request

The nonlinear PDE system is actually extracted from a research paper published in 2000 [Here is the paper link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010218099000899)

The authors solved the system by using an ordinary differential equation
integrator in Fortran[Variable-coefficient Ordinary Differential Equation solver](http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/index_last.html), which suggests this is based on the "[Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)" available in Mathematica's `NDSolve` for transient nonlinear PDE systems.

**The Following Codes have been updated**

**Further updates per @xzczd comments**

However, when I am trying to put the system into `NDSolve`, different error messages occur:

```
(*
  Dear challenger:

  If you've tried to solve this set of equations but failed, 
  please increment the following counter:

  totalHoursSacrificedHere = 8 +6/60
*)
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Predefined Constants*)
ho=-57*10^5;hp=57*10^4;ha=-25*10^6;
```

Here I convert the units into SI, so these are different from original authors'.

```
no1=410;nc1=210;nc2=240;no3=1650;na3=30;(*converted from grams to kilograms *)
ng1=1000+no1-nc1;ng2=1000-nc2;ng3=1000+no3-na3;(*Derived constants do not appear in the table *)

(*Try Leach's original data settings *)
(*ho=ho/1000;hp=hp/1000;ha=ha/1000;*)
no1=no1/1000;nc1=nc1/1000;nc2=nc2/1000;no3=no3/1000;na3=na3/1000;
ng1=ng1/1000;ng2=ng2/1000;ng3=ng3/1000;
```

I think there are typo's in the original article. The unit of pre-exponential factors should be $s^{-1}$, not $L/s$. So converting from $L/s$ into $m^3/s$ is not necessary. This can be verified by the unit of the same constants used in table 2 of the same article. Such constants were determined by the cited reference [13] of the article, which further verifies this issue.

```
Ao=569*10^9;Ap=2*10^17;Aa=5*10^8;
EoR=19245;EpR=26500;EaR=19244;
f=13/10;g=18/10;h=78/100;m=1/2;
kc=42/1000;kf=63/1000;kg=258/10000;
ρc=10;ρf=53/2;
Cc=1100;Cf=1700;
df=5*10^-5;dc=13/10000;
ϕ=98/100;
Do2m=453*10^-7;
(*Constants for boundary and initial conditions*)
Tw=600;Tgin=300;Tin=300;Yo2in=23/100;uin=53/10000;
xl=0;xr=15/100;

(*Constants not appeared apparently in literature of Leach et al*)
σ=56704*10^-12;R=83144/10000;
patm=101325;M=28956*10^-6;Pr=7/10;
A=8000/5;cg=1005;μg=2*10^-5;ν=144*10^-7;

(*Functions defined*)
ωo[x_, t_] := (1 - yc[x, t] - ya[x, t])^f *ρf*Ao*(Ybo[x, t])^m *Exp[-EoR/T[x, t]]
ωp[x_, t_] := (1 - yc[x, t] - ya[x, t])^g *ρf*Ap*Exp[-EpR/T[x, t]]
ωa[x_, t_] :=yc[x, t]*ρc*Aa*(Ybo[x, t])^h*Exp[-EaR/T[x, t]]
ρg[x_, t_] := patm*M/R/Tg[x, t]
```

The $V_{O_2}$ has been given in the article and already defined similarly as a function. There do be a series of physical constants, e.g., $\sigma$ Stefan-Boltzmann constant, universal gas constant $R$, Prantl constant $Pr\approx 1 \text{ or } 0.7$, which should be determined based on the chemical engineering background knowledge and I have included them into the equations and definitions implicitly without further clarification.

```
Vo2[x_, t_] := -Do2m*D[Ybo[x, t], x]
hmA3p[x_,t_] := (4*10^-5/df + 42/100*ug[x, t]*(2*10^-5)^(2/3)*ν^(-1/6)) A;
hA3p[x_, t_] := A*(2 + 11/10*(7/10)^(1/3)*((df*ρg[x, t]*ug[x, t])/μg)^(3/5))*kg/df;

(*Nonlinear PDEs*)
eq1 = ((yc[x, t] + ya[x, t])*ρc + ρf*(1 - yc[x, t] -ya[x, t]))*((yc[x, t] + ya[x, t])*Cc + Cf*(1 - yc[x, t] - ya[x, t]))*D[T[x, t], t] == D[((yc[x, t] + ya[x, t])*kc +kf*(1 - yc[x, t] - ya[x, t]) + (16*σ*df*T[x, t]^3)/3)*
      D[T[x, t], x], x] - ωo[x, t]*ho - ωp[x, t]* hp - ωa[x, t]*ha + hA3p[x, t] (Tg[x, t] - T[x, t]);

eq2 = 10*D[yc[x, t], t] ==nc1* ωo[x, t] + nc2* ωp[x, t] - ωa[x, t];
eq3 = 10*D[ya[x, t], t] == na3* ωa[x, t];

eq4 = ϕ*ρg[x, t]*cg*(D[Tg[x, t], t] + ug[x, t]*D[Tg[x, t], x]) == ϕ*kg*D[Tg[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
      hA3p[x, t] (T[x, t] - Tg[x, t]);
```

In the same article, all the porosity ratios $\phi'$s with different subscripts have been considered as approximately the same constant 0.98. So I followed this convention. The ϕ in equation 5 can be completely cancelled actually.

Equations 6 and 7 have been combined together with $y^s_{O_2}$ eliminated. Also by confirmation with cited [13], the $y_{O_2}$ in the initial and boundary conditions section and in equations 2 and 3, should be $y^b_{O_2}$, i.e., oxygen concentration in the bulk of the gas.

```
eq5 = ϕ (D[ρg[x, t], t] + ϕ*D[ρg[x, t]*ug[x, t], x]) == ϕ (ng2 *ωp[x,t] + (ng1 - no1) ωo[x, t] + (ng3 - no3)*ωa[x, t]);
eq6 = ϕ (D[ρg[x, t]*Ybo[x, t], t] + D[ρg[x, t]*Ybo[x, t]*ug[x, t], x] + D[ρg[x, t] Ybo[x, t] Vo2[x, t], x]) == -(no1* ωo[x, t] + no3* ωa[x, t]);
sys = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6};


tr = 2000; trs = Min[1800, tr];
(*Calculate ya[xr=15/100,t] and yc[xr=15/100,t] boundary conditions*)


convertRule = {T[x, t] -> Tw, Ybo[x, t] -> Yo2in, 
   Derivative[0, 1][yc][x, t] -> fyc'[t], yc[x, t] -> fyc[t], 
   Derivative[0, 1][ya][x, t] -> fya'[t], ya[x, t] -> fya[t]};
ode1 = eq2 /. convertRule // Simplify;
ode2 = eq3 /. convertRule // Simplify;

sol = NDSolve[{ode1, ode2, fya[0] == 0, fyc[0] == 0}, {fya, fyc}, {t, 
    0, tr}, Compiled -> False, PrecisionGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
{Plot[fyc[t] /. sol, {t, 0, trs}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotPoints -> Floor[trs]] Plot[fya[t] /. sol, {t, 0, trs}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, PlotPoints -> Floor[trs]]}

(*Initial and boundary conditions*)
ibcs={Derivative[1,0][T][xl,t]==0,T[xr,t]==Tw,T[x,0]==(UnitStep[x-xr]+1)Tgin,Derivative[1,0][Tg][xl,t]==0,Tg[xr,t]==Tgin,Tg[x,0]==Tgin,
Derivative[1,0][Ybo][xl,t]==0,Ybo[xr,t]==Yo2in,Ybo[x,0]==Yo2in,yc[x,0]==0,yc[xr,t]==fyc[t]/.(sol[[1,2]]),ya[x,0]==0,ya[xr,t]==fya[t]/.(sol[[1,1]]),(*Derivative[1,0][ug][0,t]\[Equal]0,*)ug[x,0]==uin,ug[xr,t]==uin};

fsol = NDSolve[sys~Join~ibcs, {Tg, T, yc, ya, Ybo, ug}, {x, xl, xr}, {t, 0, tr},Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 50}}}, MaxSteps -> 10^3, AccuracyGoal -> 8(*,MaxStepFraction\[Rule]1/100*)(*,(*Compiled\[Rule]False,*)WorkingPrecision\[Rule]50*)
               ]
```

> During evaluation of In[81]:= NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations. >>

Does this mean the `Method of Lines` cannot be used?

> During evaluation of In[81]:= NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution. >>

For `Method of lines` algorithm, such initial and boundary conditions should already be enough.

> During evaluation of In[81]:= NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions. >>
>
> Out[81]= {}

When I change the options `Compiled->False` and `WorkingPrecision->50`, muc more memory is needed than my PC has.

Can such precision issue be solved by just increasing the working precison? or I will have to use some `NDSolve` Options which are dedicated to such very stiff cases?

Using `IndexReduction` method gives strange results do not match the real cases. (It seems this method can only be immediately used for differential-algebraic equations with ordinary differential equations only. For those cases with "epllitic-parabolic" PDEs, tutorial indicates difference matrices should be constructed first. and I have [another question posted on the tutorial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/question-on-one-of-the-ndsolvedae-sample-codes?lq=1) actually)

```
fsol = NDSolve[sys~Join~ibcs, {Tg, T, yc, ya, Ybo, ug}, {x, xl, xr}, {t, 0, tr},Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines","SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 50}}}, MaxSteps -> 10^3, AccuracyGoal -> 8(*,MaxStepFraction\[Rule]1/100*)(*,(*Compiled\[Rule]False,*)WorkingPrecision\[Rule]50*)
               ]
```

**Further Update**

I have tried to rewrite the code per the tutorial [mentioned here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/question-on-one-of-the-ndsolvedae-sample-codes?lq=1), first construct difference matrices; then the difference equations with boundary and initial conditions; but still obtain warning message as below, and the results are different from those obtained by Leach et al(2000) article though I already added one more initial condition $y_a(x,0)=0$ than the 2000 article:

> NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended. >>

Comment: I suggest you to place those parameters and equations in the order they appeared in the paper, currently it's really frustrating to check if there's any simple mistake.

Comment: You can consider uploading it to a net-disk.

Comment: As mentioned above, you'd better not to change the order of parameters, just place them in the order they appeared in the paper so it's easier to check if they're correct. Also, it's not a good idea to include those value of parameters (`101325*29` etc.) in the equations directly, it's a potential source of mistake.

Comment: You're right, I made a lot mistakes in copying the equations. Rearranging the parameter list helps !

Comment: thank you! @bbgodfrey How can I edit the symbols the same way? it seems some special tool is used.

Comment: One way is simply to copy the symbols from [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html) or elsewhere.  Halirutin's [program](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/installing-halirutans-script-in-internet-explorer-11) can be used for more extensive copying of special  characters.  I too have a package, and I intend to write it up soon.

Comment: It would be best if Wolfram can add one more option to the "Copy As" menu command to solve it immediately. I look forward to your package. Once finished, do let me know. thank you.

Comment: And there're still mistakes, here are those I can identify: `1. ho = ho/1000; hp = hp/1000; ha = ha/1000;` is redundant; 2. `Ao = 569 10^6; Ap = 2 10^14; Aa = 5 10^5`;  3. `10*D[yc[x, t], t]` and `10*D[ya[x, t], t]` should be `D[ρ*yc[x, t], t] and D[ρ*ya[x, t], t]` where `ρ = (yc[x, t] + ya[x, t]) ρc + ρf (1 - yc[x, t] - ya[x, t]);`; 4. The unknown functions should be `{T, yc, ya, yo2s, yo2b, Tg}`, according to the article. (u should probably be eliminated, there're 7 equations anyway. )

Comment: Then, you seemed to have eliminated `eq7` in some way, and I think you haven't done it correctly, `eq6` and `eq7` should be something like `eq6 = D[ρg*ϕb*yo2b[x, t], t] + D[ρg*yo2b[x, t]*ub*ϕb, x] + 
         D[ρg*ϕb*yo2b[x, t]*Vo2b, x] == 
       (-hm)*A3*(yo2b[x, t] - yo2s[x, t]);  
eq7 = D[ρgs*ϕs*yo2s[x, t], t] + D[ρgs*ϕs*yo2s[x, t]*Vo2s, x] == 
       (-ωo)*no1 - ωa*no3*hm*A3*(yo2b[x, t] - yo2s[x, t]);
`. As to the article, to be honest I can't understand it very well, so long I can't tell how $c_p,c_{\text{pg}},d,D,u_b,V_{O_{2_b}},V_{O_{2_s}},\alpha ,\phi _b,\phi _s$ is calculated.

Comment: BTW, I usually use http://steampiano.net/msc/ to convert the special characters. halirutan's extension is quite unstable at least in my Chrome.

Comment: @xzczd thank you, this link is very useful! Is there any offline version of such conversion tools?

Comment: Yes there should be totally 7 dependent variables: (1)$T(x,t)$ (solid temperature), (2)$Tg(x,t)$(gas temperature),(3) $y_a(x,t)$(mass fraction of ash), (4)$y_c(x,t)$(mass fraction of char), (5)$u_g(x,t)$ or $(u_b(x,t)$ (velocity of gas/bulk),(6) $y^b_{O_2}(x,t)$ and (7) $y^2_{O_2}(x,t)$(mass fraction of oxygen at the bulk and surface) and seven equations. the symbols you mentioned as "cannot tell" are either constants or clearly defined functions dependent on the constants and dependent varaibles (among the seven).-- I guess $y^s_{O_2}$ and equation (7)  be eliminated per cited[13](1992)

Comment: Additionally, the initial and boundary conditions are the key to finally get the PDEs solved correctly. While, in the IBCs section, the author mentioned neither the initial nor the boundary conditions for $y^s{O_2}$. These information makes me believe $y^s_{O_2}$ should be eliminated or it will difficult to solve a PDE depedent variable without IBCs on it.

Comment: It seems the methods available in `NDSolve` cannot be used immediately on such "parabolic-elliptic" PDEs. One has to construct difference matrices, boundary conditions and initial conditions first, and then `NDSolve` can be used. I even doubt whether there is bug in some algorithm of `NDSolve` itself now: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/question-on-one-of-the-ndsolvedae-sample-codes

Comment: "Is there any offline version of such conversion tools", check this post:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/1871 . As to your new update, since I'm now at home and have no access to the new mentioned article, I'd like to stop verifying the model, I write this comment mainly to mention, the `NDSolve::bcart:` can be suppressed by using `T[x, 0] == (Tw - Tgin) (Exp[1000 (x - xr)]) + Tgin` instead of the corresponding boundary, `NDSolve::pdord` can be suppressed by using `neweq5 = D[sys[[5]], t] /. Solve[D[sys[[4]], t], Derivative[0, 2][Tg][x, t]][[1]]; ` instead of `eq5`.

Comment: @xzczd I have updated both equations and the code in this link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107463/weird-error-message-when-using-differential-algebraic-solver-in-ndsolve please help review the code. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the culprit behind is the not-strong-enough DAE solver. Using the 3rd approach in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) i.e. by descretizing the spatial derivatives manually, I managed to solve your equation set without warning, but the results seems to be different from those in the paper, I'm not sure about the reason. (For such a complicated problem there're too many possibilities! ) Anyway, I'd like to show you my solution.

Equations and parameters are the same as what you gave in the question so they're omitted in this answer.

`pdetoode` is a general purpose function for discretizing PDE to ODE, its definition can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871).

First, some preparation:

```
lb = xl; rb = xr;

xdifforder = 4;

points = 50;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];
var = {Tg, T, yc, ya, Ybo, ug};

ptoo = pdetoode[var[x, t], t, grid, xdifforder];

odevar = # /@ grid & /@ var;
```

OK, let's discretize `ibcs`:

```
odeibc = ibcs // ptoo;
```

In the next part of code, `sys` is also discretized, then the obtained equations at the "endpoints" that are duplicates of b.c.s are removed. This is the most tricky part of the solution, because equations in `sys` are coupled so it's not that easy to identify the redundant ODEs. There should be cleverer ways, but here I simply found the right ones to remove by trial and error:

```
eqngroup = {#, Complement[sys, #]} & /@ Subsets[sys, {3}];
i = 8;(*Found by trial and error*)
odeq1 = (eqngroup[[i, 1]] // ptoo)[[All, 2 ;; -2]];
odeq2 = (eqngroup[[i, 2]] // ptoo)[[All, 1 ;; -2]];
odesol = NDSolveValue[{odeq1, odeq2, odeibc}, odevar, {t, 0, tr}];

sollst = rebuild[#, grid, -1] & /@ odesol

Partition[Plot3D[#[x, t], {t, 0, tr}, {x, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ sollst, 
  3] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you very much. I got similar result as yours. I contacted the corresponding author with my questions and results half a year ago but got no response yet.

Comment: Can you please post a ready- to- work version of your code for verification so that I can try it easily?

Comment: @LCFactorization Just execute those code lines before `fsol = NDSolve[sys~Join~ibcs,……` in your question first.

Comment: The solution [this way](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16107/matlab-incorrect-computation-with-pdepe-for-parabolic-elliptic-system/22070#22070) is easy for me to understand. I will spend time in understanding you code. How long did you spend in solving the PDE system this way I am just curious?

Comment: @LCFactorization The spirit of your solution is the same as mine, the only difference is I've automate the discretization with `pdetoode` etc.. I've added some explanation for `pdetoode` in my answer, have a look. As to the timing for solving your system, I should say I'm not sure, but the upper limit is 4 hours.

Comment: @xzczd I noticed that after your latest edit, the `pde2ode` function immediately copied from [the link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation/127997#127997) does not work properly without modification. Is it possible to create a general purpose version for PDEs in the both cases?

Comment: @user6043040 No, it still works, actually I always use these questions where `pdetoode` is used as test samples before updating the `pdetoode` function. I guess you forgot to remove the ``ClearAll["Global`*"]`` line at the beginning of OP's code?

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much