# Stopping NDSolve when encountering stiffness

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am solving a differential equation for different initial conditions using `ParametricNDSolveValue`. I need to look at the value of the solution at some later point, and classify the nature of the solution. For certain starting values, the solution is well-behaved and oscillatory. For certain other starting values (which are smaller than the oscillatory ones), the solution rapidly rises to very large numbers, and Mathematica gives me a stiffness/singularity error:

```
ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz: At r == 0.0004036933699289324`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to stop NDSolve the moment it encounters stiffness and somehow let me know that this happened. I essentially only need to know the value of the starting point at which it goes from oscillatory to stiff, with high precision. At such a value, the solution should end up at an unstable equilibrium point, without oscillations or rapidly rising to large numbers. Is there a way to detect stiffness (I am assuming the problem here is stiffness) without Mathematica trying to find an extrapolated solution?

Here's the equation I am working with:

```
Potential[x_] := 5.154462413581529*^7 - 256000000*(1 - x)^2 + 128000000*(1 - x)^4 - 1.030892482716306*^8*x^2 + 8.049495987048458*^8*(1 - x)^2*x^2 + 5.154462413581531*^7*x^4

test = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(Derivative[2][t][r] + (2/r)*Derivative[1][t][r] - D[Potential[x], x] /. x -> t[r]) == 0, t[10^(-12)] == d, 
 Derivative[1][t][10^(-12)] == 0}, t[0.5], {r, 10^(-12), 1}, {d}];
```

And this is the code I am using to check this in case anyone is interested:

```
C = 0.0005;
d = 0.002; 
Under = 1; 
Monitor[Quiet[While[C >= 10^(-18), While[Under == 1, d = d - C; If[Abs[test[d]] > 1 || d < 0, Under = 0]; ]; d = d + C; C = C/10; Under = 1; ]; ], d]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NDSolve` stops itself when it believes that it has encountered stiffness.  To take advantage of this, rewrite `test` as

```
test = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(Derivative[2][t][r] + (2/r)*
    Derivative[1][t][r] - D[Potential[x], x] /. x -> t[r]) == 0, 
    t[10^(-12)] == d, Derivative[1][t][10^(-12)] == 0}, t, {r, 10^(-12), 1}, {d}]
```

In other words, obtain the entire solution `t`, not just `t[.5]`.  Then use, for instance,

```
test[.001]["Domain"][[1, 2]]
(* 0.000383406 *)
```

which shows that `NDSolve` detected stiffness at `x == 0.000383406`.  On the other hand,

```
test[.002]["Domain"][[1, 2]]
(* 1. *)
```

shows that `NDSolve` did not encounter stiffness throughout the range of integration.  Applying this to the code in the question that seeks the value of `d` for which stiffness first occurs gives

```
c = 0.0005; d = 0.002; Under = 1; Monitor[
Quiet[While[c >= 10^(-18), While[Under == 1, d = d - c; If[test[d]["Domain"][[1, 2]] < 1, 
    Under = 0];]; d = d + c; c = c/10; s = d; Under = 1;];], d]
NumberForm[s, 16]
(* 0.001701281449747991 *)
```

Note that `c` is used here instead of `C`, which is a reserved symbol in Mathematica.

**Addendum: Faster Solution**

The solution above, patterned after that in the question, requires `108 sec` on my PC to obtain an answer.  The following, which brackets the solution and successively reduces the bounds by a factor of two on each iteration,

```
dl = c; du = d; 
Do[dt = (dl + du)/2; If[Quiet@test[dt]["Domain"][[1, 2]] < 1, dl = dt, du = dt], {i, 20}]
NumberForm[du, 16]
(* 0.001701281449747996 *)
```

takes `0.000112592 sec`.

Comment: This helps a lot! Thanks! My original code used Greek letters, and it looked odd when I pasted it here. I changed them before posting which is why I have a C in there (I didn't think about reserved symbols).

Comment: @GoK  You are most welcome.  And, thanks for accepting my answer.  With respect to copying Greek characters to StackExchange, see my [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114877/1063) on how to copy Unicode, or one of the other answers there, depending on your preferences and operating system.  Alternatively, use Halirutan's script, although I have not used it myself, because [it requires interface software](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/installing-halirutans-script-in-internet-explorer-11) to work on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll use this from now on.