# ListLinePlot of a 3D function, over one of the arguments, with a range of values for the other 2 arguments

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a function of 3 arguments

```
mu[kx_, ky_, lambda_] := -(kx^2 + ky^2) - (kx^2*(kx^2 + 5*ky^2)*lambda)/(kx^2 + ky^2)^4
```

I want to plot `mu` against `lambda` for a range of values for each of `kx` and `ky` - for each pair `{kx,ky}` there will be one straight line of `mu[lambda]` as shown in the attached screenshot.

I got the screenshot using `Plot`, but that is very slow (prohibitively slow if I want to decrease `epsilon` to get better resolution).

Q1 - will it be quicker if I use `ListLinePlot` to plot this set of straight lines? (My guess is that it would be much quicker as Mathematica will only need to calculate two points (`mu[lambdaMin]` and `mu[lambdaMax]`) for each line.)

Q2 - how do I do it with `ListLinePlot`?! My guess is to first `Table` out the values of `kx`,`ky` I want to use, but this gives me a square matrix. Then I think I need to reshape this into a 2-by-many matrix then expand this by `Table`-ing over `lambda`. But I can't work out how.

Thanks in advance, apologies for such a basic question, still fairly new to Mathematica etc.

[image: output using Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ***how do I do it with ListLinePlot?***

```
ϵ = .2;
ListLinePlot[Join @@ Table[{l, mu[x, y, l]}, {x, ϵ, 1, ϵ}, {y, ϵ, 1, ϵ}, {l, {-5, 5}}]]
```

[image]

#### ***will it be quicker if I use ListLinePlot to plot this set of straight lines?***

```
timings = Table[{ϵ , First@RepeatedTiming@ 
  Plot[Evaluate[Join @@ Table[mu[x, y, l], {x, ϵ, 1, ϵ}, {y, ϵ, 1, ϵ}]], {l,  -5, 5}], 
  First@ RepeatedTiming@
   ListLinePlot[Join @@ Table[{l, mu[x, y, l]}, {x, ϵ,  1, ϵ}, {y, ϵ,      1, ϵ}, 
    {l, {-5, 5}}], PlotRange -> {-20, 20}]}, {ϵ , .05, .2, .05}] 

Grid[Prepend[timings, {"ϵ", "Plot", "ListLinePlot"}]] /. 
  x_Real :> NumberForm[x, {5, 3}] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{ccc}
>  \epsilon  & \text{Plot} & \text{ListLinePlot} \\
>  0.050 & 7.060 & 0.158 \\
>  0.100 & 0.532 & 0.048 \\
>  0.150 & 0.099 & 0.024 \\
>  0.200 & 0.057 & 0.019 \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: Thanks very much!
Bonus question, which is off-topic but refers to your answer, how did you get markdown to write out the epsilons in code sections without using TeX? 

In my question I tried copy-pasting from Mathematica but it came out as `\[Epsilon]`. I'd like to use special characters like Greek letters in future questions. 

Thanks again!

Comment: @jms547, I use [Silvia's UnicodeCopy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45046/125).

Comment: @jms547 An alternative is to use the [MMA SE userscript](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor). It adds a few useful buttons that can replace those sequences with the correct characters and more